# Negative lookbehind equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

Is there a way to achieve the equivalent of a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) in JavaScript regular expressions?  I need to match a string that does not start with a specific set of characters.

It seems I am unable to find a regex that does this without failing if the matched part is found at the beginning of the string.  Negative lookbehinds seem to be the only answer, but JavaScript doesn't has one.

This is the regex that I would like to work, but it doesn't:

`(?<!([abcdefg]))m`

So it would match the 'm' in 'jim' or 'm', but not 'jam'

Comment: Consider posting the regex as it would look with a negative lookbehind; that may make it easier to respond.

Comment: Those who want to track the lookbehind  etc. adoption please refer to [ECMAScript 2016+ compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Look-behinds were added in the 2018 spec. Chrome supports them, but [Firefox still hasn't implemented the spec](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665).

Comment: Does this even need a look behind? What about `(?:[^abcdefg]|^)(m)`? As in `"mango".match(/(?:[^abcdefg]|^)(m)/)[1]`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### [Lookbehind Assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) got [accepted](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) into the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) in 2018.

Positive lookbehind usage:

```js
console.log(
  "$9.99  €8.47".match(/(?<=\$)\d+\.\d*/) // Matches "9.99"
);
```

Negative lookbehind usage:

```js
console.log(
  "$9.99  €8.47".match(/(?<!\$)\d+\.\d*/) // Matches "8.47"
);
```

### [Platform support](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)

- ✔️ [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/)

  - ✔️ [Google Chrome 62.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545)
  - ✔️ Microsoft Edge 79.0
  - ✔️ [Node.js 6.0 behind a flag and 9.0 without a flag](https://node.green/)
  - ✔️ Deno (all versions)
- ✔️ [SpiderMonkey](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665)

  - ✔️ [Mozilla Firefox 78.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634135)
- ✔️ JavaScriptCore: [the feature](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174931) has been [merged](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/46e6b3f97425a4a7bb16fc175288903a5f74d5f2)

  - ✔️ [Apple Safari 16.4](https://webkit.org/blog/13878/web-push-for-web-apps-on-ios-and-ipados/)
  - ✔️ [iOS 16.4 WebView](https://webkit.org/blog/13878/web-push-for-web-apps-on-ios-and-ipados/) (all browsers on iOS + iPadOS)
  - ✔️ [Bun 0.2.2](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/releases/tag/bun-v0.2.2)
- ❌ Chakra: [Microsoft was working on it](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3448) but Chakra is now abandoned in favor of V8

  - ❌ Internet Explorer
  - ❌ Edge versions prior to 79 (the ones based on EdgeHTML+Chakra)

Comment: Apple has **finally** landed a commit to implement look-behind, so it should make its way into iOS and Safari updates soon(ish).

Comment: The feature has landed in Safari 16.4 beta 1 today

Answer (score 111):

Since 2018, [Lookbehind Assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) are part of the [ECMAScript language specification](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md).

```js
// positive lookbehind
(?<=...)
// negative lookbehind
(?<!...)
```

---

**Answer pre-2018**

As Javascript supports [negative lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead), one way to do it is:

1. reverse the input string
2. match with a reversed regex
3. reverse and reformat the matches

---

```
const reverse = s => s.split('').reverse().join('');

const test = (stringToTests, reversedRegexp) => stringToTests
  .map(reverse)
  .forEach((s,i) => {
    const match = reversedRegexp.test(s);
    console.log(stringToTests[i], match, 'token:', match ? reverse(reversedRegexp.exec(s)[0]) : 'Ø');
  });
```

**Example 1:**

Following @andrew-ensley's question:

```
test(['jim', 'm', 'jam'], /m(?!([abcdefg]))/)
```

Outputs:

```
jim true token: m
m true token: m
jam false token: Ø
```

**Example 2:**

Following @neaumusic comment (match `max-height` but not `line-height`, the token being `height`):

```
test(['max-height', 'line-height'], /thgieh(?!(-enil))/)
```

Outputs:

```
max-height true token: height
line-height false token: Ø
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it doesn't work when you have both lookahead and lookbehind

Comment: can you please show a working example, say I want to match `max-height` but not `line-height` and i only want the match to be `height`

Comment: It does not help if the task is to replace two consecutive identical symbols (and no more than 2) that are not preceded with some symbol. `''(?!\()` will replace the apostrophes in `''(''test'''''''test` from the other end, thus leaving `(''test'NNNtest` rather than `(''testNNN'test`.

Answer (score 71):

Let's suppose you want to find all `int` not preceded by `unsigned` :

With support for negative look-behind:

```
(?<!unsigned )int
```

Without support for negative look-behind:

```
((?!unsigned ).{9}|^.{0,8})int
```

Basically idea is to grab n preceding characters and exclude match with negative look-ahead, but also match the cases where there's no preceeding n characters. (where n is length of look-behind).

So the regex in question:

```
(?<!([abcdefg]))m
```

would translate to:

```
((?!([abcdefg])).|^)m
```

You might need to play with capturing groups to find exact spot of the string that interests you or you want to replace specific part with something else.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. See:
`"So it would match the 'm' in 'jim' or 'm', but not 'jam'".replace(/(j(?!([abcdefg])).|^)m/g, "$1[MATCH]")`

returns
`"So it would match the 'm' in 'ji[MATCH]' or 'm', but not 'jam'"`

It is pretty simple and it works!

Comment: Brilliant! Use a negative look-ahead as a workaround for older JavaScript!

Comment: can you help me to solve this also:      /\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g

Answer (score 41):

Mijoja's strategy works for your specific case but not in general:

```
js>newString = "Fall ball bill balll llama".replace(/(ba)?ll/g,
   function($0,$1){ return $1?$0:"[match]";});
Fa[match] ball bi[match] balll [match]ama
```

Here's an example where the goal is to match a double-l but not if it is preceded by "ba". Note the word "balll" -- true lookbehind should have suppressed the first 2 l's but matched the 2nd pair. But by matching the first 2 l's and then ignoring that match as a false positive, the regexp engine proceeds from the *end* of that match, and ignores any characters within the false positive.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  However, this is a lot closer than I was before.  I can accept this until something better comes along (like javascript actually implementing lookbehinds).

Answer (score 33):

Use

```
newString = string.replace(/([abcdefg])?m/, function($0,$1){ return $1?$0:'m';});
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything: `newString` will always equal `string`. Why so many upvotes?

Comment: @MikeM: because the point is simply to demonstrate a matching technique.

Comment: @bug. A demonstration that doesn't do anything is a strange kind of demonstration. The answer comes across as if it was just copy and pasted without any understanding of how it works. Thus the lack of accompanying explanation and the failure to demonstrate that anything has been matched.

Comment: @MikeM: the rule of SO is, if it answers the question *as written*, it's correct.  OP didn't specify a use case

Comment: The concept is correct, but yes it's not demo'd very well.  Try running this in the JS console...  `"Jim Jam Momm m".replace(/([abcdefg])?m/g, function($0, $1){ return $1 ? $0 : '[match]'; });`.  It should return `Ji[match] Jam Mo[match][match] [match]`.  But also note that as Jason mentioned below, it can fail on certain edge cases.

Comment: I've written [a more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111 "regex Negative Lookbehind not valid in javascript") with full descriptions of how to match and replace with both positive and negative lookbehinds.  Now that I've found this question, I've also flagged the question I answered as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 13):

You could define a non-capturing group by negating your character set:

```
(?:[^a-g])m
```

...which would match every `m` **NOT** preceded by any of those letters.

Comment: I think the match would actually also cover the preceding character.

Comment: ^ this is true. A character class represents...a character! All your non-capturing group is doing is not making that value available in a replace context. Your expression is not saying "every m NOT preceded by any of those letters" it is saying "every m *preceded by a character* that is NOT any of those letters"

Comment: For the answer to also solve the original problem (beginning of string), it must also include an option, so the resulting regex would be `(?:[^a-g]|^)m`. See https://regex101.com/r/jL1iW6/2 for running example.

Comment: Using void logic does not always have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I achieved `str.split(/(?<!^)@/)` for Node.js 8 (which doesn't support lookbehind):

```
str.split('').reverse().join('').split(/@(?!$)/).map(s => s.split('').reverse().join('')).reverse()
```

Works? Yes (unicode untested). Unpleasant? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

following the idea of Mijoja, and drawing from the problems exposed by JasonS, i had this idea; i checked a bit but am not sure of myself, so a verification by someone more expert than me in js regex would be great :)

```
var re = /(?=(..|^.?)(ll))/g
         // matches empty string position
         // whenever this position is followed by
         // a string of length equal or inferior (in case of "^")
         // to "lookbehind" value
         // + actual value we would want to match

,   str = "Fall ball bill balll llama"

,   str_done = str
,   len_difference = 0
,   doer = function (where_in_str, to_replace)
    {
        str_done = str_done.slice(0, where_in_str + len_difference)
        +   "[match]"
        +   str_done.slice(where_in_str + len_difference + to_replace.length)

        len_difference = str_done.length - str.length
            /*  if str smaller:
                    len_difference will be positive
                else will be negative
            */

    }   /*  the actual function that would do whatever we want to do
            with the matches;
            this above is only an example from Jason's */



        /*  function input of .replace(),
            only there to test the value of $behind
            and if negative, call doer() with interesting parameters */
,   checker = function ($match, $behind, $after, $where, $str)
    {
        if ($behind !== "ba")
            doer
            (
                $where + $behind.length
            ,   $after
                /*  one will choose the interesting arguments
                    to give to the doer, it's only an example */
            )
        return $match // empty string anyhow, but well
    }
str.replace(re, checker)
console.log(str_done)
```

my personal output:

```
Fa[match] ball bi[match] bal[match] [match]ama
```

the principle is to call `checker` at each point in the string between any two characters, whenever that position is the starting point of:

--- any substring of the size of what is not wanted (here `'ba'`, thus `..`) (if that size is known; otherwise it must be harder to do perhaps)

--- --- or smaller than that if it's the beginning of the string: `^.?`

and, following this,

--- what is to be actually sought (here `'ll'`).

At each call of `checker`, there will be a test to check if the value before `ll` is not what we don't want (`!== 'ba'`); if that's the case, we call another function, and it will have to be this one (`doer`) that will make the changes on str, if the purpose is this one, or more generically, that will get in input the necessary data to manually process the results of the scanning of `str`.

here we change the string so we needed to keep a trace of the difference of length in order to offset the locations given by `replace`, all calculated on `str`, which itself never changes.

since primitive strings are immutable, we could have used the variable `str` to store the result of the whole operation, but i thought the example, already complicated by the replacings, would be clearer with another variable (`str_done`).

i guess that in terms of performances it must be pretty harsh: all those pointless replacements of '' into '', `this str.length-1` times, plus here manual replacement by doer, which means a lot of slicing...
probably in this specific above case that could be grouped, by cutting the string only once into pieces around where we want to insert `[match]` and `.join()`ing it with `[match]` itself.

the other thing is that i don't know how it would handle more complex cases, that is, complex values for the fake lookbehind... the length being perhaps the most problematic data to get.

and, in `checker`, in case of multiple possibilities of nonwanted values for $behind, we'll have to make a test on it with yet another regex (to be cached (created) outside `checker` is best, to avoid the same regex object to be created at each call for `checker`) to know whether or not it is what we seek to avoid.

hope i've been clear; if not don't hesitate, i'll try better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your case, **if you want to replace** `m` with something, e.g. convert it to uppercase `M`, you can negate set in capturing group.

match `([^a-g])m`, replace with `$1M`

```
"jim jam".replace(/([^a-g])m/g, "$1M")
\\jiM jam
```

`([^a-g])` will match any char not(`^`) in  `a-g` range, and store it in first capturing group, so you can access it with `$1`.

So we find `im` in `jim` and replace it with `iM` which results in `jiM`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, JavaScript allows lookbehinds now. In older browsers you still need a workaround.

I bet my head there is no way to find a regex without lookbehind that delivers the result exactly. All you can do is working with groups. Suppose you have a regex `(?<!Before)Wanted`, where `Wanted` is the regex you want to match and `Before` is the regex that counts out what should not precede the match. The best you can do is negate the regex `Before` and use the regex `NotBefore(Wanted)`. The desired result is the first group `$1`.

In your case `Before=[abcdefg]` which is easy to negate `NotBefore=[^abcdefg]`. So the regex would be `[^abcdefg](m)`. If you need the position of `Wanted`, you must group `NotBefore` too, so that the desired result is the second group.

If matches of the `Before` pattern have a fixed length `n`, that is, if the pattern contains no repetitive tokens, you can avoid negating the `Before` pattern and use the regular expression `(?!Before).{n}(Wanted)`, but still have to use the first group or use the regular expression `(?!Before)(.{n})(Wanted)` and use the second group. In this example, the pattern `Before` actually has a fixed length, namely 1, so use the regex `(?![abcdefg]).(m)` or `(?![abcdefg])(.)(m)`. If you are interested in all matches, add the `g` flag, see my code snippet:

```
function TestSORegEx() {
  var s = "Donald Trump doesn't like jam, but Homer Simpson does.";
  var reg = /(?![abcdefg])(.{1})(m)/gm;
  var out = "Matches and groups of the regex " + 
            "/(?![abcdefg])(.{1})(m)/gm in \ns = \"" + s + "\"";
  var match = reg.exec(s);
  while(match) {
    var start = match.index + match[1].length;
    out += "\nWhole match: " + match[0] + ", starts at: " + match.index
        +  ". Desired match: " + match[2] + ", starts at: " + start + ".";   
    match = reg.exec(s);
  }
  out += "\nResulting string after statement s.replace(reg, \"$1*$2*\")\n"
         + s.replace(reg, "$1*$2*");
  alert(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This effectively does it

```
"jim".match(/[^a-g]m/)
> ["im"]
"jam".match(/[^a-g]m/)
> null
```

Search and replace example

```
"jim jam".replace(/([^a-g])m/g, "$1M")
> "jiM jam"
```

Note that the negative look-behind string must be 1 character long for this to work.

Comment: Not quite. In "jim", I don't want the "i"; just the "m". And `"m".match(/[^a-g]m/)` yeilds `null` as well. I want the "m" in that case too.