# Porting regex from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have the following regex in PHP:

```
/(?<=\')[^\'\s][^\']*+(?=\')|(?<=")[^"\s][^"]*+(?=")|[^\'",\s]+/
```

and I would like to port it to javascript like:

```
var regex = new RegExp('/(?<=\')[^\'\s][^\']*+(?=\')|(?<=")[^"\s][^"]*+(?=")|[^\'",\s]+/');

var match = regex.exec("hello,my,name,is,'mr jim'")

for( var z in match) alert(match[z]);
```

There is something that JavaScript doesnt like here, but I have no idea what it is. I've tried looking for diferences between PHP and JS regex via regular-expressions.info but I cant see anything obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you again

**Edit:**
The problem seems to lie within the positive lookbehind's but does this mean it cannot be ported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get lookbehind (and lookahead has problems in IE, so is best avoided too). But it's easy to just let those ' and " characters be part of the match, and throw them out afterwards:

```
var value= "hello,my,name,is,'mr jim'";
var match;
var r= /'[^'\s][^']*'|"[^"\s][^"]*"|[^'",\s]+/g;

while(match= r.exec(value)) {
    var text= match[0];
    if ('"\''.indexOf(text.charAt(0))!=-1) // starts with ' or "?
        text= text.substring(1, text.length-1);
    alert(text);
}
```

Or, use capturing parentheses to isolate the quotes from the text:

```
var r= /'([^'\s][^']*)'|"([^"\s][^"]*)"|([^'",\s]+)/g;

while (match= r.exec(value)) {
    var text= match[1] || match[2] || match[3];
    alert(text);
}
```

(I'm guessing your `for(var z in match)` was supposed to loop over each pattern match in the string. Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't quite work that easily.)

This may not be the best way to parse a comma-separated list; it seems a bit ill-defined for cases where you have a space or quote in the middle of a field. A simple string-indexing parser might be a better bet.

Comment: This is perfect. I stripped out the regex earlier of the lookbehinds and then used a replace function to remove the quote marks, your methods are far better! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Correct - the positive lookbehinds will not work.

But, just as some general information about regex in Javascript, here's a couple pointers for you.

You don't have to use the RegExp object - you can use pattern literals instead

```
var regex = /^[a-z\d]+$/i;
```

But if you use the RegExp object, you have to escape your backslashes since your pattern is now locked in a string.

```
var regex = new RegExp( '^[a-z\\d]+$', 'i' );
```

The primary benefit of the RegExp object is if there is a dynamic bit to your pattern, for example

```
var max = 4;
var regex = new RegExp( '\d{1,' + max + '}' );
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, as you can probably tell I normally stick to PHP, and very rarely use regex in either language. Thank you for your advice, will note this down for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

it's `(?<=)` positive look-behind what Javascript doesn't support. but be aware that Javascript implementation in different browsers vary significantly.

**Edit**: there is an [SO question devoted to workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent).

Comment: Would you say it's not worth attempting to port it, and do all the work server side instead of client side?