# replace a number (not preceding with character) with _(underscore)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to replace the numbers in the string with _number.We have to fetch the numbers only that dont begin with a character and replace them with a underscore .
Requirement : I have a string, so while processing I want to replace constants with _Constant.
example string  :"(a/(b1/8))*100"
output expected :"(a/(b1/_8))*_100"

Please suggest how to do this in asp.net code behind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the code's going to be in C# or VB.net, so it can be used as a JavaScript identifier, right? Which of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as cwallenpoole's, just in C# code behind

```
string str = '(a/(b1/8))*100';
str = Regex.Replace(str, '([^a-zA-Z])([0-9])', '$1_$2');
```

**Updated**:

```
string str = "(a/(b1/8))*100";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "([^a-zA-Z0-9]|^)([0-9])", "$1_$2");
```

Comment: this gives the partial output.

Comment: this give partial output:(a/(b1/_8))*_10_0
Expected is (a/b1/_8))*_100

Comment: @cwallenpoole's could you please tell me why 3 digit number i.e 100 is being split into two. thatz not desired.Any other edits ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a regular expression and the replace function:

```
var str = '(a/(b1/8))*100';
alert( str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])([0-9])/g, '$1_$2') );
```

So, what's going on?

- The `/`'s mark the beginning and end of the regular expression (the tool best suited to this task).
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` means "nothing which is a letter or a number".
- `[0-9]` means "a digit".
- Together, they mean, "something which is not a letter or a number followed by a digit".
- The g at the end means "find all of them".
- The `()` groups the regular expression into two parts $1 and $2
- The `'$1_$2'` is the output format.

So, the expression translates to:

> Find all cases where a digit follows a non-alphanumeric. Place a '_' between the digit and the non-alphanumeric. Return the result.

### Edit

As an aside, when I read the question, I had thought that the JS function was the desired answer. If that is not the case, please read `rkw`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992006/replace-a-number-not-preceding-with-character-with-underscore/6992038#6992074) as that provides the C# version.

### Edit 2

Bart brought up a good point that the above will fail in cases where the string starts with a number. Other languages can solve this with a negative lookbehind, but JavaScript cannot (it does not support negative lookbehinds). So, an alternate function must be used (a NaN test on substr( 0, 1 ) seems the easiest approach):

```
var str = '(a/(b1/8))*100';
var fin = str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])([0-9])/g, '$1_$2');
if( !isNaN( fin.substr( 0, 1 ) ) ) fin = "_" + fin;
alert( fin );
```

Comment: This will fall apart if his string starts with a digit. You can still use negative lookbehind or, if the character class fits, word boundaries.

Comment: Or, use an alternative for the first part with `^`

Comment: That is a point, but JS does not support a negative lookbehind.

Comment: Of course, there are [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent#642746).

Answer (score 0):

Why not try regular expressions:
That is:

search for the regex:  "[0-9]+" & replace with "_ + regex."

ie.

```
String RegExPattern = @"[0-9]+";
String str = "(a/(b1/8))*100";
Regex.Replace(str, RegExPattern, "_$1");
```

Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx

Hope that helps ya some!

Comment: You forgot about the restriction "numbers only that dont begin with a character" (by which he probably means a "word character", or non-punctuation, something like that).