# JavaScript negative lookbehind issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got some JavaScript that looks for Amazon ASINs within an Amazon link, for example

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00137QS28
```

For this I use the following regex: `/([A-Z0-9]{10})`

However, I don't want it to match artist links which look like:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Artist-Name/e/B000AQ1JZO
```

So I need to exclude any links where there's a '/e' before the slash and the 10-character alphanumeric code. I thought the following would do that: `(?<!/e)([A-Z0-9]{10})`, but it turns out negative lookbehinds don't work in JavaScript. Is that right? Is there another way to do this instead?

Any help would be much appreciated!

As a side note, be aware there are plenty of Amazon link formats, which is why I want to blacklist rather than whitelist, eg, these are all the same page:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00137QS28/
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00137QS28
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B00137QS28/
http://www.amazon.com/Product-Title-Goes-Here/dp/B00137QS28/
```

Comment: yep, negative lookbehinds are not supported.

Comment: Negative lookbehinds aren't directly supported in JS, but there are decently simple ways to implement their logic.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) is the master question for that sort of thing.  I gave [a more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111) elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case an expression like this would work:

```
/(?!\/e)..\/([A-Z0-9]{10})/
```

Comment: Nice.  Maybe `(^[\s\S]?|(?!\/e)[\s\S]{2})` so that it can match near the beginning of the input and the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 2):

`([A-Z0-9]{10})` will work equally well on the reverse of its input, so you can

1. reverse the string,
2. use positive lookahead,
3. reverse it back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a lookahead to filter the `/e/*` ones out. Then trim the leading `/e/` from each of the matches.

```
var source; // the source you're matching against the RegExp
var matches = source.match(/(?!\/e)..\/[A-Z0-9]{10}/g) || [];
var ids = matches.map(function (match) {
  return match.substr(3);
});
```