# Negative Lookbehind JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I know that a lot of people have posted a similar question but with the `g` flag, none of the "hacks" seem to work for me properly *(meaning they don't work most of the time)*. *Yes I want the `g` flag* The regex I've made is:

```
\~\![A-Za-z]+\ start(?:(?:(?:\(|,)\ ?[\w]+)*?\))\:\{([\S\s]+?)(?:(?<!\\)\}\:end)
```

[This works fine when negative look-behind *is supported*](https://regex101.com/r/aD7aH2/1). But when I do it in JavaScript. It doesn't support negative look behind. Here's the part where the problem lies:

```
(?:(?<!\\)\}\:end)
```

[What it should match](https://regex101.com/r/aD7aH2/2):

```
\}:end    <- Not this
}:end     <- This
foo}:end  <- This
```

I've tried:

- [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/1620622)
- [JavaScript negative lookbehind issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236594/javascript-negative-lookbehind-issue)

Comment: What's up with `[\S\s]`?  As far as I know, it means the same thing as `.`.

Comment: `This works fine in PCRE` - how this is relevant to javascript ? PCRE is far more powerfull, what's your question ? You might try to google some PCRE.js porting attemps, like https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre . That's the simplest thing to do if you want a richer syntax in your regexps.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's so it can match newlines.

Comment: @John `[\S\s]` is not the same as `.`, because it also matches `\n`.

Comment: To avoid relying on negative lookbehind, you need to modify the *preceding* part of the regex.

Comment: @c69 I'm not so open to the idea of adding a whole library for a single negative lookbehind

Comment: I just wrote an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111 "regex Negative Lookbehind not valid in javascript") with full descriptions of how to match and replace with both positive and negative lookbehinds, **including support for global modifiers**.  Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using lookbehind you can use lookahead

e.g.

```
abcdefg;}hijklmn#}
```

to get

```
$1 = `abcdefg;}hijklmn`
$2 = `#}`
```

using **lookbehind approach** you can do

```
(.*)(?<!#})(#})
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF7aQ1/3) (lookbehind approach)

which here prevent a duplication of `#}` by using negative lookbehind.

On the other hand, **lookahead approach** is also possible by "spawning lookahead",

let's consider our example text

```
abcdefg;}hijklmn#}
```

become

```
%a%b%c%d%e%f%g%;%}%h%i%j%k%l%m%n%#}
```

here `%`s represent to lookahead.

**How we can spawn lookahead like that?**

Let's consider **lookahead approach** regex for our example text

```
((?:(?!#}).)*)(#})
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qD9mK0/1) (lookahead approach)

A trick here is spawning lookahead together with `.` where the regex `((?:(?!#}).)*)` can be expanded to

```
((?!#}).(?!#}).(?!#}).(?!#}).(?!#}).(?!#}).) and so on
```

that means it will check for every letters to guarantee you that there is no `#}` in `(.*)`.

Thus, if apply this strategy to your regex you will get

```
\~\![A-Za-z]+\ start(?:(?:(?:\(|,)\ ?[\w]+)*?\))\:\{((?:(?!\}\:end\n)[\S\s])+)(?:\}\:end)
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mI9kW5/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
\~\![A-Za-z]+\ start(?:(?:(?:\(|,)\ ?[\w]+)*?\))\:\{([\S\s]+?)(?:[^\\]\}\:end)
```

Try this, see the demo:

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/17

Comment: Nice! But what if I wanted to change it so: `abc}:end` would not be selected. `(?:[^a]{1,1}[^b]{1,1}[^c]{1,1})` doesn't seem to work