# JavaScript Negative Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked through numerous other questions up here surrounding a negative lookbehind for JavaScript but I can't seem to mimic them.  I have the following Regex:

```
\b((?:http[s])?\S+\.\S+\.(?:\S+\.?){1,4})(?<!@)\b`
```

and the basis of this Regex is it matches web addresses like:

- `www.msn.com`
- or `http://www.msn.com`
- or `https://www.google.com`
- or `http://msdn.microsoft.com`.

However, it also matches `name@d1.d2.d3.d4` because of the numerous domain names following the `@` sign.  I need to perform a negative lookbehind for that `@` sign.

Hopefully somebody can give me a hand!

**UPDATE**

Updating to include the replacement string that I'm using to create the hyperlink out of the matched text.

```
replace(webLinkPattern, "<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"preventDualEditing(event)\">$2</a>");
```

**UPDATE 2 - ANSWER**

```
ts = ts.replace(webLinkPattern, function (url) {
    if (url.indexOf('@') != -1) {
        return url;
    }

    return url.replace(webLinkPattern, "<a href=\"http://$&\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"preventDualEditing(event)\">$&</a>");
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to match the entire e-mail, or just the domain portion of the e-mail?

Comment: I don't want it to match the email at all - I have another Regex that matches the email addresses. See, I have to take the result and turn it into a link so I need to make sure I'm not picking up email addresses.

Comment: instead of using `\S`, why not limit your set to valid characters using `[]`

Comment: @Joseph That's a pretty long list of characters for web addresses isn't it?

Comment: @mperrenoud03 you can use ranges like `[A-Za-z0-9]` for alphanumeric

Comment: @Joseph the problem with that however is that it will match everything after the `@` in those email addresses.

Comment: See also [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) as well as this [more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111 "regex Negative Lookbehind not valid in javascript") with full descriptions of how to match and replace with both positive and negative lookbehinds.  This is a duplicate of those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, so you'll have to handle this in your own code. One option is simply to include the `@` in the result, and then discard the match if the `@` is there:

```
replace(/(?:\b|@)(?:https?)?\S+\.\S+\.(?:\S+\.?){1,4}\b/,
        function(url) {
          if(url.indexOf('@') > -1)
            return url;
          return '<a href="' + url + ' target="_blank"' +
                 ' onclick="preventDualEditing(event)">' + url + '</a>';
        }
       );
```

Alternatively, you can check for a preceding `@` in the callback, even without including it in `url`:

```
replace(/\b(?:https?)?\S+\.\S+\.(?:\S+\.?){1,4}\b/,
        function(url, pos, str) {
          if(pos > 0 && str.charAt(pos - 1) == '@')
            return url;
          return '<a href="' + url + ' target="_blank"' +
                 ' onclick="preventDualEditing(event)">' + url + '</a>';
        }
       );
```

(Note that I've also changed `http[s]` to `https?`, which is what you meant. `http[s]` is the same as `https`, since `[s]` is a character class matching any character that's `s`.)

Comment: I don't think this will work in my situation because I need to create a real link out of it during a REPLACE - so I need to make sure I'm not matching email address.

Comment: @mperrenoud03: You can use a callback instead of a simple string as your replacement. If you post your replacement-string, I'll update my answer with a callback you can use.

Comment: I updated the question with the exact answer that worked for me - but your direction got me there.