# How to convert a string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i convert a string with regex, so that it contains just alphabetical (a-z) or a hyphen. 
It should get rid `" ' ! ? .` and so on. Even if they appear multiple times.

```
// if i have e.g.
var test = '"test!!!"';

// how can i get the value "test"?
```

Can sombody help. RegEx is totaly new to me.

Comment: You can start here http://stackoverflow.com/faq and then when you're done with that you can continue here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Can you post your current regex attempt please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the characters you don't want:

```
'"test!!!"'.replace(/[^a-z-]/gi, '')
```

`[^a-z-]` matches all characters but a-z and the hyphen. The `/g` flag makes the regexp apply multiple times. The `/i` flag (optional) makes it match case-insensitively, i.e. not replace upper-case characters.

Comment: @Bergi Are you sure? What JavaScript engine are you using? Make sure that you don't forget the `/g` flag.

Comment: Yes, but you forgot it at first…

Comment: whould this also replace a hyphen which appears between a-z caracters, like "word-word"?

Comment: @user1745578 Yes. The expression matches characters, and does not care about order.

Comment: so how whould it be if it whould care about order?
like matching the hyphen after an end and ignoring it when it appears inbetween?

Comment: Then you'd use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). However, [lookbehind assertions are not supported in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779578/javascript-negative-lookbehind). Therefore, you'd have to join the matches of allowed words instead of filtering out the invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple: You build a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches [everything except](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) those chars you want and remove them by [replacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) each occurence (*global* flag) with the empty string:

```
return str.replace(/[^a-z-]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 str = "hello!! my + name $ is slim-shady";
   console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z-]+/g, ''));

$ node src/java/regex/alphanum.js 
hellomynameisslim-shady
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replace` method for any string variable and specify the characters you wish to remove.

Here's an example:

```
 var sampleString = ("Hello World!!");    //Sample of what you have. 
 var holdData = sampleString.replace(/!!/gi, '');
 window.alert(holdData);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "test!!!";
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z\-]/g,"");
```