# How can you extend jquery.validate.unobtrusive with a new validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to be able to validate fractions on my form using jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.  I have changed my html markup to include 'fraction'

```
<input class="span12 data fraction" data-val="true" name="FrontHoodHeightL" id="FrontHoodHeightL" type="text" value="29 15/16">
```

in the class name and I have included the following javascript in my page.

```
$.validator.addMethod("fraction", function (value, element, param) {
    var fracExp = new RegExp("(?:-(?!0))?\d+(?:(?: \d+)?/\d+)?");
    return fracExp.test(value);
});
```

but the method never seems to get called.  What step am I missing to wire this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more step: Use [`addClassRules`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules) to add a class rule that uses your new method:

```
$.validator.addClassRules("fraction", {
    fraction: true
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/X2m4U/

*Note*: It looks like you are trying to use negative lookbehinds in your regex. This [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/641407/497356) with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me in the direction of the documentation where you found this?  I looked for a while and couldn't find anything.  You are also correct about the regex statement.  I'll have to figure out a different one that will work.

Comment: @PlTaylor: I've added a link to the documentation for `addClassRules`. I am not sure there is explicit documentation that walks you through adding a rule like this, I'm just pretty familiar with the plugin.