# Javascript Regex - unexpected behaviour on faking lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to code a widget that collates Tweets from multiple sources as an exercise (something similar exists [here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets), but a) the list option offered there did not load any of my lists, and b) it is a useful learning exercise!).   As part of this, I wanted to write a regex which replaces a Twitter handle ('@' followed by characters) with a link to the user's Twitter page. However, I did not want false positives for, for instance, an email address in a tweet.

So, for instance, the replacement should send

```
Hey there @twitteruser, my email address is address@gmail.com
```

to

```
Hey there <a href="http://twitter.com/twitteruser">@twitteruser</a>, my email address is address@gmail.com
```

Guided by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent), which suggested that I needed some way of replicating negative look-behinds in Javascript, I wrote the following code:

```
tweetText = tweetText.replace(/(\S)?@([^\s,.;:]*)/ig, function($0, $1){
    return $1 ? $0 + '@' + $1 : '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + $0 + '">@' + $0 + '</a>'
});
```

However, in the cases where the final part of the ternary operator is triggered, $0 contains the '@' symbol. This was unexpected for me - since the '@' was not enclosed in parentheses, I expected $0 to match '([^\s,.;:]*)' - that is, the username of the Twitter user (after, and without, the '@').  I can get the desired functionality by using $0.substring(1), but I would like to further my understanding.

Could someone please point out what I have misunderstood? I am quite new to Regexs, and have never written them in Javascript, nor have I ever used negative look-behinds.

Comment: `$0` is always the **whole** pattern. `$1` is the first parenthesized group, ``$2` is the second, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case, instead of trying to match an optional non-space before the `@`, and rejecting the match if you find one, why not just require a space (or the beginning of the string) before the `@`?

```
tweetText = tweetText.replace(
    /(^|\s)@([^\s,.;:]*)/g,
    '$1<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>'
);
```

Not only is this simpler, but it's likely to be quite a bit faster too, since the regexp needs to consider much fewer potential matches.

Comment: Perfect, thank you - I considered doing this at first, but didn't realise that you could mix special characters (like the caret) in with normal patterns. This works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As is standard behaviour in most REGEX implementations, match zero is the whole match (including, as part of it, any sub-matches - even any that are marked as non-capturing), then any subsequent matches are the captured sub-matches. Check out www.regular-expressions.info. For example:

```
console.log('hello, there'.match(/\w+(?:,) ?(\w+)/));
```

Gives you the array

```
["hello, there", "there"] //the first sub-match is non-capturing
```

JavaScript does not support look-behinds but there are simulations for this, none perfect, [like the one I wrote](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Feb/Simulating+REGEX+look-behinds+in+JavaScript-153?highlight=regexp). JavaScript's REGEXP implementation in general is weaker than that of some other languages. Some examples of omissions include:

- look-behinds
- named atomic groups
- most of the modifiers (though the key ones are there - global, case-insensitive and multi-line)
- crucially, the ability to capture sub-groups whilst also matching globally

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't realise that $0 returned the whole match, that explains a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be complicating things too much. Try this to retrieve the usernames and then make your own helper function to create the markup.

```
var getTwitter = function (str) {
  var re = /[^\w](@\w+)/g,
      matches = [],
      tweets = []
  while (matches = re.exec(str))
    tweets.push(matches[1])
  return tweets
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/gLvX4/

Comment: Thanks for this - the reason that I felt I needed negative lookbehinds was that sometimes (in fact, often) the username tag will occur at the beginning of the text, which this example doesn't catch (though, to be fair, I didn't include that in my example). If there were some way of matching 'a non-word character or the beginning of the string', that would be perfect, but I don't think /[^\w|^]/ will behave as I hope.

Comment: @scubbo: There is: `(^|\W)`.  See my answer for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating, is not that complicated. You can do everything once on a single line of code, just do this `\W@(\w+)`

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/Wugvd/

```
//make twitter username links
function linkTwitterNames(elm){
    elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replace(/\W@(\w+)/g, ' <a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>');
}
```