# C# creating a string which will be parsed, based on user input fails when they enter a tokenizing character

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I know what is going on, but i was trying to make it so that my .Split() ignores certain characters.

sample:

```
1|2|3|This is a string|type:1
```

the parts "This is a string" is user input The user could enter in a splitting character,  | in this case, so i wanted to escape it with \|.  It still seems to split based on that.  This is being done on the web, so i was thinking that a smart move might actually be just JSON.encode(user_in) to get around it?

```
1|2|3| This is \|a string|type:1
```

Still splits on the escaped character because i didnt define it as a special case.  How would i get around this issue?

Comment: Seems like `This is \|a string` should be surrounded by quotes, as in `"This is \|a string"`.  That would make it work properly with the CSV parsers; the only user input that wouldn't work is an inner quotation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use Regex.Split instead and then split on | not preceded by a .

```
        // -- regex for | not preceded by a \
        string input = @"1|2|3|This is a string\|type:1";
        string pattern = @"(?<!\\)[|]";
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }
```

Comment: So, instead of javascript doign something like    x.Split("|") i would do something like x.Split(/(\\)|/);   Its been a bit since ive done regex in javascript

Comment: Im going to see if i can give this a go and see if this will work.

Comment: If you need to do this in javascript this question/answer should point you in the correct direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your delimiter with something special first, next split it and finally replace it back.

```
    var initial = @"1|2|3|This is \| a string|type:1";
    var modified = initial.Replace(@"\|", "@@@");
    IEnumerable<string> result = modified.Split('|');
    result = result.Select(i => i.Replace("@@@", @"\|"));
```

Comment: This assumes of course that the input string will never contain "@@@".