# Javascript lookbehind stopped at the first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to parse (in JS) an e-mail address that originally, instead of a @ has a dot. Obviously I want to show the @ instead of the dot.

```
var mail = "name.domain.xx"
```

We have two cases:

1. *name* contains some dots itself and they are backslashed:

   ```
   name\.surname.domain.xx
   ```
2. *name* contains only regular characters (non dots)

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) topic I found a way to implement the negative lookbehind and this is what I did:

```
mail = mail.replace(/(\\)?\./, function ($0, $1) { return $1?$0:"@"; });
```

but it's not working because in case (1) it finds the *\.*, it does not touch it, and of course it stops.

On the other end, if I use the option *g*, it substitute also the third dot obtaining *name.surname@domain@xx*

Now, is there a way to say:
I want to look in the whole string but I want to stop in the first match?
I hope I explained myself.

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplier just to replace the second last . for @?
Or do you expect also name.surname@uk.co and similar?

Comment: Yes I also expect dots in the domain side

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood when first answering your question. So I have changed my answer.

If you don't put the /g flag, it will just replace the first match, meaning you can look for the first punctuation without a `\` in front of it. Second you can replace all the `\.` belonging to the user part of the email with a regular punctuation.

http://jsfiddle.net/GLVNY/2/

```
var emailSingle = 'myname.domain.com',
    emailDouble = 'my\\.name\\.another\\.name.domain.com',
    regAt = /([^\\])\./,
    repAt = '$1@',
    regPunct = /\\./g,
    repPunct = '.';

emailSingle = emailSingle.replace(regAt, repAt).replace(regPunct, repPunct);
emailDouble = emailDouble.replace(regAt, repAt).replace(regPunct, repPunct);

alert('emailSingle: ' + emailSingle + '\nemailDouble: ' + emailDouble);
```

Comment: It is possible you just do not replace all \. and only first .

Comment: @kuncajs That is possible to do yes.

Comment: @thebreiflabb: thanks! It works great but I have to take care of the subdomains as well. At this point I will probably leave the address as it is...explaining the notation.

Comment: But I cannot believe that there is no way to start from left, skip all the \. and match the first .
It's so frustrating..

Comment: @user2283224 Oh does the string actually contain the `\\` character before the punction between the names, and not in the domain part? Then there should be a solution!

Comment: @thebreiflabb: yes, that's what I wrote in the question. And yes! That's working! Thank you very much!! I am trying to understand how, but it works!