# How do I split this line (in JavaScript) on the colons, except if the colon is preceded by http or https?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split this line:

```
at myFunc http://mysite.com/test.php:13:24
```

into this:

```
at myFunc http://mysite.com/test.php
13
24
```

I've tried using regexes (see below) but they're wrong:

```
line.split( /[^http]:/ );
line.split( /[^http][:]/ );
line.split( /(?!http):/ );
line.split( /(?!http)[:]/ );
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Search for "_lookbehinds_" and "_lookaheads_" in regular expressions. This should show you the way.

Comment: I appreciate the help but you'll notice I was using one above and it still didn't work, so I'm not understanding *lookaheads* properly (and JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind).

Comment: Javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature

Comment: @DonRhummy: Yes, but searching for it would reveal this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/548696

Comment: @Tadeck How does that help me? I don't see how to apply that to my need to split on the colon except where preceeded by http. They're replacing characters to find matches, but I need all the characters, just split. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have lookbehinds :(

#### Hack: Reverse the string

```
var reverse = function(s) { return s.split('').reverse().join(''); };
var parts = reverse(line).split( /:(?!ptth)/ ).map(reverse).reverse();
```

#### Tweaked problem #1: Match colon not followed by //

```
var parts = line.split( /:(?!\/\/)/ );
```

#### Tweaked problem #2: Match only the last two colons

```
var parts = line.match( /(.*):(.*):(.*)/ ) ;
parts.shift();
```

Comment: Your "Tweaked problem #1" is so perfect, so simple. I should have seen it. Thanks!