# JavaScript JSon string decode

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string:

```
{\"description\": \"PSY - Gangnam Style (\\uac15\\ub0a8\\uc2a4\\ud0c0\\uc77c) \\n\\u25b6 NOW available on iTunes: http:\\\/\\\/Smarturl.it\\\/psygangnam\\n\\u25b6 Official PSY Online Store US \\u0026 International : http:\\\/\\\/psy.shop.bravadousa.com\\\/\\n\\u25b6 About PSY from YG Ent.: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/YGfamilyAboutPSY\\n\\u25b6 PSY's Products on eBay: http:\\\/\\\/stores.ebay.com\\\/ygentertainment\\n\\u25b6 YG-eShop: http:\\\/\\\/www.ygeshop.com\\n \\n===============================\\nPSY CONCERT \\\"HAPPENING\\\"\\n2013.4.13. SAT 6:30PM\\nTHE SEOUL WORLD CUP STADIUM\\nYouTube LIVE@ http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/officialpsy\\nTickets: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/PsyHappeningKor\\nEnglish Booking: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/PsyHappeningEng\\n===============================\\n\\nFor More Information @\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/officialpsy\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/psy_oppa\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/ygent_official\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/me2day.net\\\/psyfive\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.psypark.com\\nApp Store: http:\\\/\\\/goo.gl\\\/l9TU6\\nGoogle Play: http:\\\/\\\/goo.gl\\\/UiEn1\\n\\n\\u00a9 YG Entertainment Inc. All rights reserved.\"}
```

And i want to parse it with `Json` and it's fail. i try to convert the `\"` with `"` with :

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/\\"/gi, '"');
```

And it change it to :

```
{"description": "PSY - Gangnam Style (\\uac15\\ub0a8\\uc2a4\\ud0c0\\uc77c) \\n\\u25b6 NOW available on iTunes: http:\\\/\\\/Smarturl.it\\\/psygangnam\\n\\u25b6 Official PSY Online Store US \\u0026 International : http:\\\/\\\/psy.shop.bravadousa.com\\\/\\n\\u25b6 About PSY from YG Ent.: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/YGfamilyAboutPSY\\n\\u25b6 PSY's Products on eBay: http:\\\/\\\/stores.ebay.com\\\/ygentertainment\\n\\u25b6 YG-eShop: http:\\\/\\\/www.ygeshop.com\\n \\n===============================\\nPSY CONCERT \\"HAPPENING\\"\\n2013.4.13. SAT 6:30PM\\nTHE SEOUL WORLD CUP STADIUM\\nYouTube LIVE@ http:\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/officialpsy\\nTickets: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/PsyHappeningKor\\nEnglish Booking: http:\\\/\\\/smarturl.it\\\/PsyHappeningEng\\n===============================\\n\\nFor More Information @\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/officialpsy\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/psy_oppa\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/twitter.com\\\/ygent_official\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/me2day.net\\\/psyfive\\nhttp:\\\/\\\/www.psypark.com\\nApp Store: http:\\\/\\\/goo.gl\\\/l9TU6\\nGoogle Play: http:\\\/\\\/goo.gl\\\/UiEn1\\n\\n\\u00a9 YG Entertainment Inc. All rights reserved."}
```

But here i get :

```
PSY CONCERT \\"HAPPENING\\"\\n2013.4.13. SAT 6:30PM
```

In one of the rows and i want to know if there is any decode method to decode the string to be valid for parse to json object?

Comment: `JSON.parse(validJSON)`

Comment: Your input is not legal JSON.

Comment: I know the input is not legal and i want to know if there is any function to decode the string to valid json string

Comment: It look like you have to make sure that `\\\"` will be replaced with `'`, before you replace every `\"` with `"`. By the way, it would have been nice, you had narrowed your problem a little bit down and could just present a small sample string instead of this monster of a string.

Comment: It appears to be a string of JSON that was re-encoded as a JSON *String*. Perhaps try to patch the source so it only encodes once? Or, parse twice to match: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(tmp))`.

Comment: How do you get this string? Is it an ajax response? Is it a literal - then what delimiters does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string seems to be double-escaped but missing its outer delimiters.

```
var str = '{\\"description\\": \\"PSY - Gangnam Style (\\\\uac15\\\\ub0a8\\\\uc2a4\\\\ud0c0\\\\uc77c) … .\\"}';
var jsonStr = JSON.parse('"'+str+'"'),
    obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the best solution, but evaluating your string before you parse it to JSON should work:

```
eval("tmp = \"" + tmp + "\";");
var tmpJSON = JSON.parse(tmp);
```

But keep in mind that you are evaluation a presumably unknown string, which is not really safe. Maybe there is a decoding function out there, that does the same.

So why should this work?

You string looks like a string, that I would write when I write a piece of code. It has all the escape backslashes that are needed to print a quote or a backslash itself. But those escape characters shouldn't be really inside the string, they are just there to define what the string should look like. So, writing `var str = "He said \"ok\"";` will produce a string like `He said "ok"`. But since your string actually contains the escape characters, it would be defined like this instead:

```
var str = "He said \\\"ok\\\"";
```

which will produce a string like this:

> He said \"ok\"

Now everything inside of `eval` is interpreted as a piece of code. So when I write:

```
eval("str = \"" + str + "\";");
```

the line of code that gets executed is:

```
str = "He said \"ok\"";
```

which results in the desired unescaped string:

> He said "ok"

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as basilikum's approach, and likely also not as correct as the double-parsing approach that Bergi and Jonathan Lonowsky suggest, but you could use a [Javascript negative lookbehind equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/), along these lines:

```
str.replace(/\\+"/gi, function(s){return (s.length % 2) ? s : s.slice(0,-2) + '"';})
```

This is definitely more secure than evaluating the string.