# Regex - avoid match if pattern prefixed with // - comment outs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex (JS.match) pattern `/@import ['"](.*)['"]/g` allowing for the external files inclusion so e.g.

`@import "/my/path"` returns `/my/path`

all works as expected but I would like to enable commenting out with `//` and `/* */`

so if string contains `//@import "/my/path"` or `/* @import "/my/path" */` then there should be NO match.

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: What about `(/*|//)` and `(*/)?` around your regex?

Comment: Something like this: /(/*|//) @import ['"](.*)['"](*/)/g, but need to escape slashes.

Comment: @Barmar it is not a duplicate since looking behind is one thing but it also needs to look forward due to closing `*/`

Comment: @ParkashKumar your solution is wrong as it should NOT match when // or /*

Comment: @Marcin Ohhh, my bad! I thought it should match when // or /*

Comment: Do you have multi-line comments with `/* */`?  If not, and if you just want to avoid matches, something like `/^\s*@import ['"](.*)['"]/g` might work.

Comment: Do you have to do it in one regexp? Why not first check for a comment, and skip the line, then check for `@import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?![/*])[^/* ]@import ['"](.*?)['"]
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN7nX7)

**Update**

```
(?![/*])[^/* ]@import ['"](.*?)['"](?![^/]*?\*\/)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/gN3zC0)

**Update #2**

Use below regex with `m` flag:

```
(?:(?![/*]])[^/* ]|^ *)@import ['"](.*?)['"](?![^*]*?\*\/)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/oV2oU2)

Comment: Thanks @Revo, its almost there, the only thing it doesn't account for is commenting out multi lines with `/*\n\n*/` e.g. (can't add break line in comments but I hope you know what I mean) `/*
@import "/my/path14" 
\n@import "/my/path14" 
*/`

Comment: @revo, almost there, just one more issue, when /* is followed by break line and then multiple imports, each on its own line, it seems to include all of them except the last one, here is an example - http://regex101.com/r/zP4cJ7