# Negative lookbehind regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all strings that start with an @ unless they have other characters in front of the @ as well. Simple example: in `@one @two and bla@three` I want to match `@one` and `@two` but **not** `@three`. It's for highlighting usernames in a chatroom.

These strings can be anywhere in a sentence (right at the start or in the middle).

I actually thought that `(?![a-zA-Z])@[a-zA-Z]+` should work but it still matches `@three` too.

Comment: You want negative lookbehind, not negative lookahead. But JS doesn't have that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent for a workaround.

Comment: So, essentially you're looking for a pattern that matches an "@something" which has a space in front? Or in other words: what characters _other_ than a space should be allowed in front of the "@"?

Comment: It should start with a space or be the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: `/(?:^| )(@\S+)/` should do just fine. Or `@[a-z]+`, if there can be something else used as separator than ` `.

Comment: That would be `/(^| )@[a-z]+/ig` then... :)

Comment: The only problem is that this also matches the space before @two

Comment: @raina77ow Looks like you nailed it :) http://regex101.com/r/gE5cE4

Comment: @mixedCase Of course, you'll have to use capturing groups - there's no look-behind in JS.

Comment: One of my favorite things to do with regex questions is show people that they don't need to use lookaround.  Give `\B@\w+` a try.

Comment: Ha amazingly simple. Please turn it into an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regex look around, you can use a simple regex like this:

```
\B@\w+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK4oU2/1)**

[image]

Comment: As an additional example:  http://regexr.com/3apif 
on the RegExr site if you go to reference on the left, then anchors it'll explain \b

RegExr is my go to for creating RegEx as the reference guides are right there without being in the way.

Comment: @MicTech you could use `(?<=^| )@\w+`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza JavaScript doesn't support that.

Comment: @MicTech true, forgot about that. Anyway, this question was posted 1 year ago and also marked as resolved, so guess it solved OP problem.