# jquery rss double return line ¶

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to remove all single carriage returns but not two or more carriage returns if they are followed by each other.

remove ¶  but not ¶¶

i.e.

```
s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

removes all return lines

Comment: You can try negative lookaheads. Can clarify if you want to remove `\n` or only `\r`?

Answer (score 0):

```
                obj.Summary = obj.Summary.replace(/(\n){2,}/g, '¶');
                obj.Summary = obj.Summary.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
                obj.Summary = obj.Summary.replace(/[¶]/g, '\n\r');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent  And inspired by Jason S answer: http://jsfiddle.net/an8KD/2/