# Match first occurrence of semicolon in string, only if not preceded by '--'

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for Java that matches if there is a semicolon that does not have two (or more) leading '-' characters.

I'm only able to get the opposite working: A semicolon that has at least two leading '-' characters.

```
([\-]{2,}.*?;.*)
```

But I need something like

```
([^([\-]{2,})])*?;.*
```

I'm somehow not able to express 'not at least two - characters'.

Here are some examples I need to evaluate with the expression:

```
; -- a           : should match
-- a ;           : should not match
-- ;             : should not match
--;              : should not match
-;-              : should match
---;             : should not match
-- semicolon ;   : should not match
bla ; bla        : should match
bla              : should not match (; is mandatory)
-;--;            : should match (the first occuring semicolon must not have two or more consecutive leading '-')
```

Comment: How many semicolons can be in string? Is string like `-;--;` correct?

Comment: Also do we want to forbid only leading `-`? What about strings like `x--;`?

Comment: @Pshemo The first one has to match (updated my question accordingly). The second one must not match, just to keep things simple. Otherwise I would need to write a complete parser and thats not the intention of my small application.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this regex matches what you want

```
String regex = "[^-]*(-[^-]+)*-?;.*";
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/U4j0q3)

Explanation: `matches` will accept string that:

- `[^-]*` can start with non dash characters
- `(-[^-]+)*-?;` is a bit tricky because before we will match `;` we need to make sure that each `-` do not have another `-` after it so:

  - `(-[^-]+)*` each `-` have at least one non `-` character after it
  - `-?` or `-` was placed right before `;`
- `;.*` if earlier conditions ware fulfilled we can accept `;` and any `.*` characters after it.

---

More readable version, but probably little slower

`((?!--)[^;])*;.*`

Explanation:

To make sure that there is `;` in string we can use `.*;.*` in matches.
But we need to add some conditions to characters before first `;`.

So to make sure that matched `;` will be first one we can write such regex as

```
[^;]*;.*
```

which means:

- `[^;]*` zero or more non semicolon characters
- `;` first semicolon
- `.*` zero or more of any characters (actually `.` can't match line separators like `\n` or `\r`)

So now all we need to do is make sure that character matched by `[^;]` is not part of `--`. To do so we can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms for instance:

- `(?!--)[^;]` before matching `[^;]` `(?!--)` checks that next two characters are not `--`, in other words character matched by `[^;]` can't be first `-` in series of two `--`
- `[^;](?<!--)` checks if after matching `[^;]` regex engine will not be able to find `--` if it will backtrack two positions, in other words `[^;]` can't be last character in series of `--`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a negative lookahead!

This regex will match any string which does not contain your original match pattern:

```
(?!-{2,}.*?;.*).*?;.*
```

This Regex matches a string which contains a semicolon, but not one occuring after 2 or more dashes.

Example:  [image: Regex Working]

Comment: Which software did you use?

Answer (score 0):

How about using this regex in Java:

```
[^;]*;(?<!--[^;]{0,999};).*
```

Only caveat is that it works with up to `999` character length between `--` and `;`

#### [Java Regex Demo](http://fiddle.re/ndwp5)

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava. I would prefer a solution without groups. But in general your solution works.

Comment: Hi anubhava I have created a question almost dedicated to you! lol. I really like that tecnhique. Could you check it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808793/regex-technique-to-disallow-variable-length-lookbehind-using-or/

Answer (score 0):

How about just splitting the string along `--` and if there are two or more sub strings, checking if the last one contains a semicolon?

Comment: I would prefer a solution where I can call just .matches(), because all other statements in my class work this way. Just for reading purposes.

Comment: @RichardW. That's fine; however, if it is for readability's sake, some of these answers are far less readable (if you care about _understandability_) than two or three calls which make the task obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
^(?:(?!--).)*;.*$
```

In other words, match from the start of the string (`^`), zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by a semicolon.  But replacing the dot with `(?:(?!--).)` causes it to match any character *unless it's the beginning of a two-hyphen sequence (`--`)*.

If performance is an issue, you can exclude the semicolon as well, so it never has to backtrack:

```
^(?:(?!--|;).)*;.*$
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed your comment that the regex should work with the `matches()` method, so I padded it out with `.*`.  The anchors aren't really necessary, but they do no harm.