# Javascript: equivalent regex for negative lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression that will captures all double quotes " in a string, except for those that are escaped.

For example, in the following String will return the first quote only:

```
"HELLO\"\"\"
```

but the following one will return 3 matches:

```
"HELLO\"\""\""
```

I have used the following expression, but since in JavaScript there is no negative lookbehind I am stuck:

```
(?<!\\)"
```

I have looked at similar questions but most provide a programmatic interface. I don't want to use a programmatic interface because I am using Ace editor and the simplest way to go around my problem is to define this regex.

I suppose there is no generic alternative, since I have tried the alternatives proposed to the similar questions, but non of them exactly matched my case.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no equivalent for all cases - some can and some can't be emulated depending on the requirement.

Comment: Yes, I also had this feeling and I guess my requirement represents a case that cannot be emulated. I am sure there is a proof somewhere explaining why lookbehind cannot be always emulated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this workaround:

```
(^|[^\\])"
```

`"` only if preceded by any char but a `\` or the beginning of the string (`^`).

But be careful, this matches two chars: the `"` AND the preceding character (unless in the start-of-the-string case). In other words, if you wan't to replace all these `"` by `'` for example, you'll need:

```
theString.replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, "$1'")
```

Comment: Yes, this is also the first regex I came up with. But as you said this will not work because it will capture `""` in the String `\""`, whereas I only need to capture the later `"`.

Answer (score 0):

The code I assume you are trying to run:

```
while ( matcher = /(?<!\\)"/g.exec(theString) ) {
    // do stuff. matcher[0] is double quotes (that don't follow a backslash)
}
```

In JavaScript, using this [guide to JS lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111):

```
while ( matcher = /(\\)?"/g.exec(theString) ) {
  if (!matcher[1]) {
    // do stuff.  matcher[0] is double quotes (that don't follow a backslash)
  }
}
```

This looks for double quotes (`"`) that optionally follow a backslash (`\`) but then doesn't act when it actually does follow a backslash.

If you were merely trying to count the number of unescaped double-quotes, the "do stuff" line could be `count++`.