# Negative Lookbehind: Match a substring that's not preceded one of a set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

## Question

How do you define a regular expression that will match each substring that:

- ends a line
- is not preceded by one of a given set of characters

## Case

I have a function that removes hardcoded newlines from strings of text, so they will reflow properly. The function works fine, apart from intelligently handling hyphenation.

This is a simplified version of what I have for hyphens.

```
function (string) { return string.replace(/-\n/g, "") }
```

It works on things it should work on, no problem. So this...

```
A hyphen-
ated line.
```

...becomes...

```
A hyphenated line.
```

But it goes too far, and doesn't handle dashes properly, so these examples get garbled:

```
"""
Mary Rose sat on a pin -
Mary rose.

Mary Rose sat on a pin --
Mary rose.
"""
```

The function should only consider the `-\n` pattern a match if it's not preceded by a hyphen or any kind of whitespace character.

Comment: There's an [answer to a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/1253428), but the answer lacks any explanation, so I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: what is the expected output for the second example?

Comment: No match - it should be the same. The rest of the function already replaces the newlines with spaces for any line that doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your pattern to this:

```
function (string) { return string.replace(/\b-\n/g, "") }
```

With a word boundary `\b` that is the limit between a word character and an other character.

Comment: So this will only match if the hyphen is preceded by a letter or number? Nice.

Comment: @CarlSmith: Yes, but the underscore too (that is a member of the `\w` character class), however, I assume it will not be a problem.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks. This worked perfectly for me; it was a drop in replacement that fixed the problem. @anubhava's solution is nice too, as a general solution for SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var repl = string.replace(/([^\s-])-\n/g, "$1");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL8dB7/1)