# Wrap words in a string with strong tags given a list of words once and in order

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have an input which I want to match to a list of strings but I want to match each input word once in order per line.

Ie

```
var input = "One Two Three".split(" "),
    matchPattern = new RegExp('(' + input.join('|') + ')', 'i'); //Replace appropriately  

//Given the following, output as per comment

"One Two Three".replace(matchPattern, "<strong>$1</strong>"); 
//<strong>One Two Three</strong>    

"One One Three".replace(matchPattern, "<strong>$1</strong>"); 
//<strong>One</strong> One <strong>Three</strong>

"Two Three One".replace(matchPattern, "<strong>$1</strong>");
//<strong>Two Three</strong> One
//In this case: 
// match One if not after One Two or Three
// match Two if not after One Two or Three
// match Three if not after One or Three (Two already matched)
```

To clarify, what I am asking is to:

1. Test each word in the string with each input word
2. Once a word is found, wrap it with a strong tag and remove that word from the input test
3. Continue with the next word and so on

I attempted to do all this with negative lookbehinds, but it seems javascript cannot handle this and all the workarounds I could find either don't work with a collection of words or require reversing the string to be tested and using negative lookaheads. I don't think either of these solutions would be ideal as I plan on running this test against 50~500 strings.

[Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: Your expected output does not match your explanation. Why is "One" not matched by itself in the first example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry. It is matched in the first example (One Two Three). In the second example (One One Three) One is matched once as per requirment

Comment: Hm never mind, on second thought I believe I understand the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

try this, just note my replace regex is contrived:

```
"Two Three One".replace(/\b\w+\b/gi, "<strong>$&</strong>");
```

## EDIT

is this more what you want:

[image: result]

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum  One Dolor Foo Two Bar Baz Three Lorem Three Quux One Two";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value,
      aVals = val.match(/\b\w+/gi);

  aVals.forEach(function(val) {
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(val+'{1}', 'i'), '<span style="color: coral;">$&</span>' );
  });

  // console.log(), essentially
  document.body.innerHTML += text;
})
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer wraps all words with strong tags and ignores the key requirement of only wrapping words, that occur in the input, once and in order.

Comment: This is getting closer to what I want but this will fail my third example (Two Three One), One shouldn't be wrapped in this case. Also I was hoping to do this with a single regex rather than a regex and a loop. Might not be possible I guess