# Don't Grab Word With Regex If It Has Tags Around It JS

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I am having trouble with this regex, and TBH I am not even sure if it possible.

Ok so basically if the text has `[code]` tags around it, the text inside will not be parsed. Let me show you what I mean:

```
[b]This text will appear bold[/b]
[code] [b]This text will not appear bold, but the bold tags will still be shown[/b] [/code]
```

So basically I am trying to check and see if the text has `[code]` tags around it. I have tried this regex:

```
/((?!\[code\])\[b\](.*)\[\/b\](?!\[\/code\]))/gi
```

So basically I thought the `(?!\[code\])` would not display the text if it had that around it, but it still is not working. So even if the text has `[code]` around it, the text inside will be higlighted, but the `[code]` tag will not be. How would I go about ONLY showing the bold if it does not have the code tags around it?

Comment: That's a negative lookbehind. Javascript doesn't support it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get this to work though?

Comment: It would be better to parse the text, figure out where the code blocks are, and then apply formatting to non-code portions.

Comment: Try: `string.replace(/(\[code\]\s*\[b\][\S\s]*\s*\[\/b\]\s*\[\/code\])/g, '').match(/\[b\]([\S\s]*?)\[\/b\]/g);` that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid something the way is to match it first and to capture it. To replace text enclosed between `[b]` tags except when theses tags are between `[code]` tags, you can write:

```
txt=txt.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|\[b\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/b\]/g, 
    function (m, g1, g2) { return g1 ? g1 : '<b>' + g2 + '</b>'; 
});
```

So when group 1 exists it is returned without change. When it is not defined the replacement string is returned.

Comment: Thank You!! Brilliant! I will test it when I get home

Comment: What do the 'm, g1, g2' represent? And how do you get that? Sorry I do not exactly understand that part. Also, I tested it, and it is working perfectly!

Comment: @MichaelJones: `m, g1, g2` are random names (I have chosen them). The meaning of these variables is determined by their positions in the parameters of the function (first param, second param...). The first parameter `m` is the whole match, the second parameter `g1` is the first capturing group, the third parameter `g2` the second capturing group, etc. if you need more groups in the function (and if these groups exist in the pattern). So in other words, you can give the names you want to these variables.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes much more sense. Thank You!