# How to match all words starting with dollar sign but not slash dollar

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all words which are starting with dollar sign but not slash and dollar sign.
I already try few regex.

```
(?:(?!\\)\$\w+)

\\(\\?\$\w+)\b
```

**String**

```
$10<i class="">$i01d</i>\$id
```

Expected result

```
*$10*

*$i01d*
```

but not this

```
*$id*
```

After find all expected matching word i want to replace this my object.

Comment: `\$` ======> `$` .... or it should be `\\$`

Comment: Why not `$id`? Is this a blacklisted word? Are there any other blacklisted words?

Comment: $id is not blacklisted word. but i want to exclude all word which start with \$ and $id one of this.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Cheers

Comment: What is your definition of a "word"?

Comment: Is your intent to replace the `$id` strings with something after you match them? In that case, you might want to consider using template strings instead.

Comment: @torazaburo yes you are right i want replace this string with my object.

Comment: You should add that important bit of information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to eliminate escape sequences first, and then match the cleaned-up string:

```js
s = String.raw`$10<i class="">$i01d</i>\$id`

found = s.replace(/\\./g, '').match(/\$\w+/g)

console.log(found)
```

Comment: I like this simplification. But it's going to be hard to get from here to the OP's desire to interpolate the `$id` strings.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem here is that you need a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), however, JavaScript does not support it. It's possible to emulate it crudely, but I will offer an alternative which, while not great, will work:

```js
var input = '$10<i class="">$i01d</i>\\$id';
var regex = /\b\w+\b\$(?!\\)/g;

//sample implementation of a string reversal function. There are better implementations out there
function reverseString(string) {
  return string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var reverseInput = reverseString(input);

var matches = reverseInput
  .match(regex)
  .map(reverseString);

console.log(matches);
```

It is not elegant but it will do the job. Here is how it works:

JavaScript *does* support a lookahead expression (`(?>)`) and a negative lookahead (`(?!)`). Since this is the reverse of of a negative lookbehind, you can *reverse* the string and *reverse* the regex, which will match exactly what you want. Since all the matches are going to be in reverse, you need to also reverse them back to the original.

It is not elegant, as I said, since it does a lot of string manipulations but it does produce exactly what you want.

[See this in action on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hD0xT4/1)

**Regex explanation** Normally, the "match **x** long as it's not preceded by **y**" will be expressed as `(?<!y)x`, so in your case, the regex will be

```
/(?<!\\)\$\b\w+\b/g
```

[demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/rD6eU5/1) (not JavaScript)

where

```
(?<!\\) //do not match a preceding "\"
  \$ //match literal "$"
  \b //word boundary
  \w+ //one or more word characters
  \b //second word boundary, hence making the match a word
```

When the input is reversed, so do all the tokens in order to match. Furthermore, the negative lookbehind gets inverted into a negative lookahead of the form `x(?!y)` so the new regular expression is

```
/\b\w+\b\$(?!\\)/g;
```

Comment: This is a cute idea and has been presented elsewhere on SO such as on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent), but in this case I think there are simpler approaches.

Answer (score -1):

This is more difficult than it appears at first blush. How like Regular Expressions!

If you have look-behind available, you can try:

```
/(?<!\\)\$\w+/g
```

This is NOT available in JS. Alternatively, you could specify a boundary that you know exists and use a capture group like:

```
/\s(\$\w+)/g
```

Unfortunately, you cannot rely on word boundaries via /b because there's no such boundary before '\'.

Also, [this](http://regexr.com/) is a cool site for testing your regex expressions. And [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) explains the word boundary anchor.

Comment: @torazaburo, it would be much more helpful to simply provide the necessary adjustment. /(?:^\s*|\s)(\$\w+)/g

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a language that supports negative lookback assertions you can use [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/nT0dW0/1).

```
(?<!\\)\$\w+
```

I think this is the cleanest approach, but unfortunately it's not supported by all languages.

This is a hackier implementation that may work as well.

```
(?:(^\$\w+)|[^\\](\$\w+))
```

This matches either

1. A literal `$` at the beginning of a line followed by multiple word characters. Or...
2. A literal `$` this is preceded by any character *except* a backslash.

Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/yA7nQ2/3).

Comment: It's a working example that matches `>$i01d`. I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: The OP said s/he wants to match **words**.

Comment: If you use capturing groups, you can easily access the matches. `\1` and `\2` respectively.

Comment: By the way can you provide the code surrounding this regexp, in other words how it would be used?

Comment: Addressed to @vlaz

Comment: By the way, standard terminology is "look-behind".