# How to find char if there is not another one before

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string

```
{'lalala'} text before \{'lalala'\} {'lalala'} text after
```

I want to get open bracket `{` but only if there is no escape char `\` before.

Kind of `/(?:[^\\])\{/` but it doesn't work at first statement.

Comment: The typical approach is to match on `(^|[^\\])\{`, and then when replacing, put back the character before the curly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: Should it be possible to escape ``\`` with itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach is to match the non-`\` preceding character (or beginning of string), and then put it back in your replacement logic.

```js
const input = String.raw`{'lalala'} text before \{'lalala'\} {'lalala'} text after`;

function replace(str) {
  return input.replace(/(^|[^\\])\{'(\w+)'\}/g, 
    (_, chr, word) => chr + word.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(replace(input));
```

Comment: I didn't know how to apply beginning string. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's where [`^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret) comes in: it anchors a piece of regex to the start of the string (or the line, in `m` multiline mode). Because a 'valid' opening bracket is either at the start of a string or after a non-`\` character, we can use the following regex:

```
/(?:^|[^\\])\{/g
```

I added the `g` global flag because we want to match all 'valid' opening brackets. Example use:

```js
console.log("{'lalala'} text before \\{'lalala'\\} {'lalala'} text after".match(/(?:^|[^\\])\{/g))
```

If you want to use the regex in a replace, you might want to capture the character before the bracket, as that gets replaced as well.

Comment: But your solution is replacing the `\{'lalala'}` part.

Comment: I didn't know how to apply beginning string. Thank you as well.

Comment: @torazaburo I need to double-escape the `\`s (although I'm pretty sure I did that already)