# negative lookbehind regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

Question: how to match any word that is not preceded by `.`?

In the context of a code syntax highlighter, unlike: [Negative lookbehind equivalent in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent), I don't want to reverse string then combine with lookahead nor reverse the matches order (like $1$0) since I concat multiple regex with `|`, nor use XRegExp, nor use string delimiters `^`, `$`, `.`.

With PCRE I would simply do: `/(?<!\.)\b[a-z]\w+/gi`

As I keep forgetting how to simply solve this out I would like to know if there is a recurrent pattern I can remember for mimicking negative look-behinds in JavaScript. Using look-ahead and reversing the matching logic always gets me dizzy!

Also most answers in SO use string delimiters, so it's not the same difficulty.

This is the closest I got: `/((?!\.) )\b[a-z]\w+/`, https://regex101.com/r/9hw2Y2/1, but it matches a one length char before my match (can see in green with PCRE flavor selected).

Comment: @wiktor, it is not aduplicate, one answer suggests reversing string, 1 has a known width match nothing similar with my conditions here, please help!

Comment: Why reverse when you need an optional group? See [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/3832970).

Comment: my regex is much longer than just that it looks more like `/("(?:\\"|[^"])*")|('(?:\\'|[^'])*')|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)|(<[^>]*>)|(!==?|(?:[\[\](){}.:;,+\-?=]|&lt;|&gt;)+|&&|\|\|)|\b(\d+|null)\b|\b(true|false)\b|\b(new|getElementsBy(?:Tag|Class|)Name|getElementById|arguments|if|else|do|return|case|default|function|typeof|undefined|instanceof|this|document|window|while|for|switch|in|break|continue|length|var|(?:clear|set)(?:Timeout|Interval))(?=\W)|(?!\.)([a-zA-Z][\w\d_]*)|(?:(?=\W))(\$|jQuery)(?=\W|$)/g` and I want to append this bit to my current regexp. So i can't just reverse the matches

Comment: Parsing *code* with *regex*? You are still bound to use the solution I linked to. Reversing a string to use a lookbehind is not really the most efficient way to do it. Adding the optional group and checking it in the code is much cleaner. You cannot use a lookbehind anyway, it is not supported, and there is no similar regex construct in JS regex.

Comment: It doesn't help me, I edited my question please reopen or give me a solution! SO purpose is to help each other...

Comment: The answer is simple: **It is *NOT* possible with plain JS regex**. And the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/3832970) does not even hint at string reversing.