# Splitting a path when the path delimiter is used in a component name

Tags: javascript, split, path

This feels like a silly question, but I have a string like:

```
aaaa/bbb\/ccc
```

The `\/` represents an escaped delimiter being used in the name of a path component.

So, the string represents two path components `aaaa` and `bbb/ccc`

This string is generated based on a need to create a path from path components where the need is to use / as the delimiter between components and / may also appear in a component name. This is the reason behind the need to escape / when it appears in a component name.

There may be two or more components.

Using a regex like `(?:\\\/|[^\/])+` is close to what I am looking for, but when considering the string `this/is\/a/\/str\\/ing`, it fails to split it into the components `this` & `is\/a` & `\/str\\` & `ing`.

Instead, the final component is determined to be `\/str\\/ing`.

My question is what does the javascript code look like that would allow me to split paths into path components when the component delimiter can be used in the name of a component?

In the example above, I would want to end up with two strings `aaaa` and `bbb/ccc`?

Is there a standard function that deals with this or would I need to use a regex to help me split?

Thank you.

Comment: Will there only be two components?

Comment: There can be one or more components.

Comment: This string is generated based on a need to create a path from path components where the need is to use / as the delimiter between components and / may also appear in a component name. I hope this is good enough. This is the reason behind the need to escape / when it appears in a component name. It is being used in an electron app which may also be running in the browser.

Comment: This seems poor design choice. see: [Is it possible to use “/” in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename), but also a duplicate: [JS regexp to split string based on character not preceded by backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831307/js-regexp-to-split-string-based-on-character-not-preceded-by-backslash)

Comment: @pilchard these paths are not related to filenames or posix paths. the context is different. I agree, I wish another choice had been made.

Comment: @pilchard That other SO question is close, but not quite. I changed the regex to ```(?:\\\/|[^\/])+``` but it will not properly split ```this/is\/a/\/str\\/ing``` which should have the components ```this``` & ```is\/a``` & ```\/str\\``` & ```ing```.

Comment: Are there any characters that are not allowed/won't appear in the string?

Comment: @pilchard all characters are allowed in the string, including unicode characters. I am beginning to think the decision made was a really bad one. I can only add it was not made by me. I argued against this and something better like keeping the components in an array and not as a string)

Comment: Why should `aaaa/bbb\\/ccc/ddd\/eee/fff/ggg` give  components ``bbb\`` and `ccc` and not `bbb\\/ccc` according to the comment in the given answer?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Because ```\``` is being used as an escape character. So, to use ```\``` in a component name, it too needs to be escaped...hence ```\\``` becomes ```\``` in the component name.

Comment: @pilchard I would love to know what you think of my answer...

Comment: @Thefourthbird I would love to know what you think of my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a match, you might use:

```
(?:[^\n\/\\]+|\\[\\\/]?)+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` No capture group

  - `[^\n\/\\]+` Match any char except a newline `/` or `\`
  - `|` Or
  - `\\[\\\/]?` Match `\` and optional `\` or `/`
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B6zmY2/1)

Then in the matches, you can replace `\/` with `/`

```js
const regex = /(?:[^\n\/\\]+|\\[\\\/]?)+/g;
[
  String.raw `aaaa/bbb\/ccc`,
  String.raw `this/is\/a/\/str\\/ing`,
  String.raw `aaaa/bbb\\/ccc/ddd\/eee/fff/ggg`,
  String.raw `this/is\/a/dumb/str\\/ing`,
  String.raw `aaaa/\\bbb`
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[0].replace("\\/", "/")))
);
```

If a lookbehind [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) you might use split with an alternation to match 2 scenario's where the string should split.

Then you can replace `\/` with `/` for the result array using Array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for example.

```
(?<=\\\\)\/|(?<!\\)\/
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\\\\)\/` Match `/` when directly preceded by `\\`
- `|` Or
- `(?<!\\)\/` Match `/` when not preceded by `\`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVYZIZ/1)

```js
[
  String.raw `aaaa/bbb\/ccc`,
  String.raw `this/is\/a/\/str\\/ing`,
  String.raw `aaaa/bbb\\/ccc/ddd\/eee/fff/ggg`,
  String.raw `this/is\/a/dumb/str\\/ing`,
  String.raw `aaaa/\\bbb`
].forEach(s => console.log(
  s
  .split(/(?<=\\\\)\/|(?<!\\)\//)
  .map(m => m.replace("\\/", "/"))));
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you are indicating that my regex will work (or probably does), however, if lookbehind is supported, there is a cleaner regex that can be used. I believe in your case, the second pass over the components is still required to convert ```\/``` into ```/```.

Comment: hummm...for some reason when I run your code snippet, it is giving me a script error. If I place ```matches = path.match(/(?<=\\\\)\/|(?<!\\)\//g);``` in my solution code, nothing is matched. Perhaps lookbehind is not supported for me.

Comment: @JamesHudson Then in your environment the lookbehind is not supported. I think this shortened pattern would also work. `(?:[^\n\/\\]+|\\[\\\/]?)+` See https://regex101.com/r/B6zmY2/1

Comment: Ok. Ya, no support for lookbehind. I did verify with my three test cases that your shortened pattern produces the same results. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesHudson I have added another example with that shortened pattern.

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer. I wish I could get rid of the second pass over the individual components so they would display properly.

Comment: @JamesHudson I am not sure if you can do that as the `\/` part can also be in the middle of a match and you can not skip matching characters that way.

Comment: I agree. The second pass is needed. I'll give you the answer because the correct regex is the key to the solution and your is better.

Answer (score 1):

First, because this involves javascript and its escaping rules, the string `aaaa/bbb\/ccc` needs to be `aaaa/bbb\\/ccc`.

This is my current solution:

```
  //path = "aaaa/\\bbb";
  //path = "this/is\\/a/dumb/str\\\\/ing";
  path = "aaaa/bbb\\/ccc";
  
  console.log("Path: ", path);

  const matches = path.match(/((?:[^\/\\]|\\\/|\\\\|\\)+)/g);

  console.log("M: ", matches);

  const pathComponents = matches.reduce((accumulator, component) => {
    component = component.replace("\\/", "/");
    accumulator.push(component);
    return accumulator;
  }, []);

  console.log("Path Components: ", pathComponents);
      
  pathComponents.forEach((component) => {
    console.log(`C: ${component}`);
  });
```

I need to run the matches through a second pass so I can convert the match:

```
bbb\\/ccc
```

Into something that will be displayed properly. Without the second pass, it would display as

```
bbb\/ccc
```

and needs to display as:

```
bbb/ccc
```

**Case #1**

```
path = "aaaa/\\bbb";
```

I see displayed:

```
C: aaaa
C: \bbb
```

**Case #2**

```
path = "this/is\\/a/dumb/str\\\\/ing";
```

I see displayed:

```
C: this
C: is/a
C: dumb
C: str\\
C: ing
```

**Case #3** (similar to #2)

```
path = "aaaa/bbb\\/ccc";
```

I see displayed:

```
C: aaaa
C: bbb/ccc
```

SUCCESS in all cases.

I believe I have caught all of the edge cases here.

Turns out this is a harder problem than I originally thought.

Comment: This answer is not entirely my own, but was developed via https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/ozeic0/splitting_a_path_when_the_path_delimiter_is_used/h81poik/?context=3

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = String.raw `aaaa/bbb\/ccc/ddd\/eee/fff/ggg`;
console.log(a.replace(/\\\//g, "|").split("/").map(x => x.replaceAll("|", "/")));
```

Comment: While that it close, it fails for ```aaaa/bbb\\/ccc/ddd\/eee/fff/ggg``` in which there should be components ```bbb\``` and ```ccc```. It produces a single component ```bbb\\/ccc```

Comment: I would love to know what you think of my answer...

Comment: I think that it's a poor design choice as mentioned above. Store the separate path values in a string array or replace the / delimiter with | or a comma to avoid any ambiguity. For example, `aaaa|bbb/ccc|ddd`. Then there is no ambiguity around the / and no need to escape. I'm not sure `\/` has any effect anyway, which is part of your problem. For example const a = 'aaa\/bbb' is interpreted in the same way as const a = 'aaa/bbb'. Can you actually escape a forward slash?

Comment: Or to avoid delimiter ambiguity if you absolutely must use `/` as the delimiter, use a text qualifier, i.e. `"aaaa"/"bbb/ccc"`, which is a CSV file standard approach.

Comment: The text qualifier is a good idea. I will play with it and see how it works. The storage format being used is JSON. I will have to see if, like CSV, it supports the idea as well as CSV does. Of course, I believe one would need to handle a similar case where a component name included the ```"``` character as well.