# JavaScript Regex How to exclude letter replacement when the letter is start/end/between of some special words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want replace `M` in the following text with `April`

*Sample Text:*

> dddd yy a**M**5 May May SUM MMMM 56 MM **M**

*Expected result:*

> dddd yy a**April**5 May Mars SUM MMMM 56 MM **April**

---

Really i want **ignore** replacment **when**:

- `M` is start of `May` and `Mars`
- `M` is between some `M` Like: `MMMM` or `MM` or `MMM`
- `M` is end of `SUM`

---

I tried the following code but it dose not exclude special words from replacement:

```
text.replace(/[^May|Mars|MMMM|MM|MMM|SUM]M/g,"April")

// Incorrect result>>   dddd yy aM5AprilayAprilay SUMAprilMMM 56AprilMApril
```

Comment: You need to read a tutorial that eplains what `[]` means in regexp. It has nothing to do with excluding words like that.

Comment: What you want to do requires a negative lookbehind, but Javascript doesn't have this. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent for workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be matching all those unwanted parts first:

```js
var text = 'dddd yy aM5 May May SUM MMMM 56 MM M';
console.log(text.replace(/\bM(?:a(?:y|rs)|M+)|SUM|(M)/g, function(match, p1) {
    return p1 ? 'April' : match;
}));
```