# Regex Splitting with Negative Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

The string I am trying to split:

`string1, string2, string\,3, string4`

I want to split the above string on each comma, except when the comma is escaped with a backslash.

I am unable to utilize negative lookbehind in my JavaScript.

My attempt:

`var splits = "string1, string2, string\,3, string4".split("(?<!\\\\),");`

None of the commas are being recognized.

Potential solutions: after research, I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) SO question.  However, I don't understand the workarounds well enough to change the above code to the replace the use case.

Comment: What should the output look like for this input: `"foo\\, bar"`? (ie. when you escape the escape character). Or this: `"foo\\\, bar"`?

Comment: Do you also need to get empty matches? Like in `foo,,bar` => `['foo', '', 'bar']`?

Comment: Is your input really `string\,3,` or rather `string3\,`? That second comma is really there in string3? Otherwise, `(?<!\\),`

Comment: Yes I wanted empty matches. The output should look like:
"string1 " 
"string2 "
"string\,3 "
"string4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
s.match(/(?:[^,\\]|\\.)+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ummgKz/2/). It will match 1 or more chars other than comma and backslash, or any char that is escaped with a literal backslash.

Note that the string literal should have a double backslash to define a literal backslash.

```js
var splits = "string1, string2, string\\,3, string4".match(/(?:[^,\\]|\\.)+/g);
console.log(splits);
```