# Alternative to negative lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I'm specifically using Ruby but I'm curious... say I'm trying to match a decimal followed by at least three digits.

Here's the regexp: `/(\.\d{5,})/`

Without using a negative lookbehind, how would I make this only match if it follows either A) a space or tab or newline, or B) is the start of a string?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid negative lookbehind? Are there any other constructs you also need to avoid?

Comment: In this case, javascript doesn't allow for negative lookbehind.

Comment: But you said that you're using Ruby. If you want a JavaScript regular expression, you should ask for that, rather than for a Ruby regular expression that avoids one particular feature that Ruby regular expressions have but JavaScript regular expressions lack.

Comment: @ruakh: His question is clear enough, he just wants to do that with Ruby flavors without using negative lookbehind.

Comment: @Max: Look at this post, you might find something interesting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: Can't it match the previous character?

Comment: @Gawil: My issue is that the OP's stated requirement is trivial to satisfy -- just use *positive* lookbehind (`/(?:^|(?<=[ \t\n])(\.\d{5,})/`) -- but I suspect that doing so won't satisfy his/her *real* requirement. Conversely, if the stated requirement were "write a JavaScript regex that is equivalent to the Ruby regex `/(?:^|(?<=[ \t\n])(\.\d{5,})/`", then that requirement would be literally *impossible* to satisfy, but it could nonetheless be possible to satisfy the *real* requirement, if we knew what that was.

Comment: @Gawil My real requirement, as stated, is curiousity. I'm trying to learn more about regexp, and I wanted to know if I was missing a simple way to ignore a match if it followed a character/new line/space/start of string.

Comment: @Max: in the link I posted above, there is a way to do that. It's not pure regex though, but it's close.

Comment: can someone please answer following : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59403483/11264185

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first consider how it would be done with a lookbehind.
Then we just check if before what we capture is the start of the line, or a whitespace:

```
(?<=^|\s)(\.\d{5,})
```

We could simply change that lookbehind to a normal capture group.
Which means a preceding whitespace also gets captured.  But in a replace we can just use or not use that capture group 1.

```
(^|\s)(\.\d{5,})
```

In the PCRE regex engine we have \K

> \K : resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously
>   consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

So by using that \K in the regex, the preceding space isn't included in the match

```
(?:^|\s)\K(\.\d{5,})
```

A test [here](http://rubular.com/r/4spsKV2dEh)

However, if you use Rubi's `scan` with a regex that has capture groups?
Then it seems that it only outputs the capture groups `(...)`, but not the non-capture groups `(?:...)` or what's not in a capture group.

For example:

```
m = '.12345 .123456 NOT.1234567'.scan(/(?:^|\s)(\.\d{5,})/)
=> [[".12345"], [".123456"]]

m = 'ab123cd'.scan(/[a-z]+(\d+)(?:[a-z]+)/)
=> [["123"]]
```

So when you use scan, lookarounds don't need to be used.