# Javascript Regex to match standalone S without matching apostrophe S

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a stand alone `s` ignoring case. I do not want to match an s that is preceded by an apostrophe. My current regex is `/\b[s]\b/ig` and my test string is and the `S` on lines 2 and 3 should be the only matches.

```
Men's
S
Just S Things
Somethings
```

Regexr: http://regexr.com/3geo2

Comment: What you need is a negative lookbehind, but Javascript doesn't support it. A cheap way around is to reverse the string and do a negative lookahead instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) for example.

Comment: You can try `\s+s\s+`

Comment: @MaxZoom you submitted as a reply and not an answer but this seems to work for me! Toss it up as an answer so I can mark appropriately :D

Comment: @MaxZoom You edited your first answer that was working. Your previous answer worked for me. `(^|\s)s($|\s)`

Comment: I have posted it as the answer, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a short experimentation I have came up with the following regex

```
(?:\s|^)s(?:\s|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kxZulx/2)

Answer (score 1):

One [trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) you could use is to use alternation between a non-capturing and a capturing expression, and then in your post-processing of the regex matches, discard the matches that don't have a capture group.

The regex would be:

```
/'s|(\bs\b)/ig
```

And if you were using it to do replacement operations, it would be used like:

```js
var str = "Men's\nS\nJust S Things\nSomethings";

var updatedStr = str.replace(/'s|(\bs\b)/ig,
  (match, captureGroup) => captureGroup ? "<S>" : match
);

console.log(updatedStr);
```