# Match pattern except under one condition Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a patterned with regex except when the pattern is escaped.

Test text:

```
This is AT\&T&reg; is really cool Regex
```

You can see with my \& I'm manually escaping. And therefore, do not want the regex to match.

Regex:

```
const str = 'This is AT\&T&reg; is really cool Regex'

str.replace(/\&(.*?)\;/g, '<sup>&$1;</sup>');
```

Expected output

```
This is AT&T<sup>&reg;</sup> is really cool Regex
```

Hard to explain I guess but when the start of this regex looks for a `&` and ends with a `;` however, if `&` is preceded with at `\` like `\&` than do not match and look for the next `\&(.*?)\;`

Comment: Your `str` does not contain a literal ``\``. You need to double ``\`` inside a string literal to define a literal backslash.

Comment: do you want to be able to escape backslashes?

Comment: I want \& to never match and go on to lookup the next &(.*?)\;

Comment: A better example, I guess, would be `var s = "This is AT\\&reg;&reg; is really cool Regex";`. Your current problem can be solved with `/&\w+;/g` regex.

Comment: This is not a question, this is "write code for me". What's worse, you didn't say what language you're using and the task is underspecified (e.g. you haven't answered transistor09's question yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) 
This regex works fine with the example
`/(?<!\\)\&(.*?)\;/g`

### Edit 1

To workaround in JS you can use `[^\\]` that will match everything except backslash. The overall regex `/[^\\]\&(.*?)\;/g` It works for your example.

Comment: Webstorm IDE hates it but I love you! Thanks

Comment: @MatthewHarwood JavaScript doesn't have look-behind.

Comment: JavaScript [doesn't seems to support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) lookbehind assertions so it should be tested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it is JS. There is workaround for JS https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347100/1079966 (also check out other answers in this thread)

Comment: @Anton The JS tag was only added a minute ago.

Comment: `str.replace` clearly points that it is JS snippet, but tag was missed, true

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript have no support for lookbehind assertions - it is possible to add some custom substitution logic to achieve desired results. I've updated test string with examples of different kinds of html entities for test purposes:

```js
const str = '&T;his is AT\\&T&reg; is & really &12345; &xAB05; \\&cool; Regex'

console.log(str.replace(/&([a-z]+|[0-9]{1,5}|x[0-9a-f]{1,4});/ig, function (m0, m1, index, str) {
    return (str.substr(index - 1, 1) !== '\\') ? '<sup>' + m0 + '</sup>' : m0;
}));
```