# Match a certain string after certain character with Regex

Tags: regex

I had a paragraph:

```
aaa-bbb-cc/my-text">my-text sas
//domain.com/my-text'> this is my-text
```

I want to replace all string 'my-text' to 'my replace tex' if they are not just after character '/' like:

```
aaa-bbb-cc/my-text">my replace text sas
//domain.com/my-text'> this is my replace text
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<!\/)my-text
```

`(?<!\/)`Negative Lookbehind

since it's javascript, which does not support negative lookbehind, you can do this way:

```
(?=([^\/]|^)(my-text))
```

group 2 is your expect.

Comment: with Javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: It doesn't work with me  str = str.replace((/?=([^\/]|^)(my-text))/gi, "my replace text");  and this work: str = str.replace(/([\/])?my-text/gi, function($0,$1){ return $1?$0:'my replace text';})

Comment: thanks @mynotmypt, (?=([^\/]|^)(my-text)) only can be used for match, can't do replace with it.