# Javascript Regex negative lookbehind Alternative

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

Looks like it is not first question about look-behind, but I didn't find an answer.

Javascript has no (positive|negative)look-behind requests.

I need a regular expression that match *.scss file name, but didn't match the names like *.h.scss.
With look-behind request is looks like:

```
/(?<!(\.h))\.scss$/
```

How can I do this in javascript?
I need this regular expression for webpack rules "test" parameter, so the javascript regex required only.

Comment: can someone please answer following: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59403483/11264185

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/641407

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*\.h\.scss$).*\.scss$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YbO6VE/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?!.*\.h\.scss$)` - a negative *lookahead* failing the match if the string ends with `.h.scss`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\.scss` - a `.scss` substring at the...
- `$` - end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You can list all possible subpatterns that doesn't match `.h` and build an alternation:

```
/(?:[^.].|\.[^h]|^.?)\.scss$/
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, this working solution too, but answer of [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is more simplier to understand.