# Javascript how to skip split based on space delimiter exept the space that is followed by certain sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse the target string `"Soup base vegetarian no msg "`
to be an array of `["Soup", "base", "vegetarian", "no msg"]`
so basically parse by space except when space follows the word `"no"`
I tried below and the result wasn't exactly right:

```
let test = "Soup base vegetarian no msg ";
console.log(test.split(/([^no]\s)/g));
```

what regex should I use to achieve such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `match` instead of `split`:

```js
var str = "Soup base vegetarian no msg ";

var arr = str.match(/(?:\bno\s+)?\S+/g);

console.log(arr);
//=> ["Soup", "base", "vegetarian", "no msg"]
```

Regex `(?:\bno\s+)?\S+` optionally matches word `no` followed by 1+ whitespaces before matching 1+ non-whitespace characters.

Comment: This regex seems to work even without the word boundary patter `\b`.

Comment: Yes it will work without word boundary also but then it will also match words like `casino`

Answer (score 1):

You can use  this regex `((no )?\w+)`.

**Explanation:-**

- `(no )?` will either match `no`(no with space or nothing(?))
- `\w+` will match word(match more than one alphabet(a-z or A-Z))

```js
var str = "Soup base vegetarian no msg";
var arr = str.match(/((no )?\w+)/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347100/1977018) using split.

The code is so weird because JS [does not support negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent).

```js
let test = "Soup base vegetarian no msg ";
var tokens = reverse(test)
  .split(/ (?!on)/g)
  .filter(x => x)
  .map(reverse);

console.log(tokens);

function reverse(s) {
  return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```