# regexp ignore some context after matching

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

i want to solve regular expression in javascript for:

ignore } character wrapped context by quote.
but must match } character out of quote.

example:
"The sentense { he said 'hello, {somebody}', she said 'hi, {somebody}' } got a something."

result:
{ he said 'hello, {somebody}', she said 'hi, {somebody}' }

thanks for your help

Comment: This lacks context (can `{` `}` constructs be nested? can a quoted part contain escaped `"` symbols? if so, what's the escape syntax? what library or language or tool are you using? specifically, what's the regex flavor/syntax?) and, indeed, a question (do you have an attempt that doesn't quite work? are you stuck somewhere? or do you just expect us to write the code from scratch?).

Comment: Now your "result" doesn't even appear in the input string.

Comment: sorry. i had a mistake. modfied it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The context is a little vague, but assuming you want the result to contain everything inside of (and including) the **outer** curly braces, you can just use `/{.*}/g`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var regex = /{.*}/g;
var string = 'The sentense { he said "hello, {somebody}" } got a something.';

console.log(string.match(regex)[0]);
```

Or if you want to grab all three components, you can use the slightly-more-complicated regex 
`/({.*(?={))(.*(?<=.*}))(?:.*)}(.*)/g`:

Breaking this down:

1. `({.*(?={))` - Group anything up to the second `{`
2. `(.*(?<=.*}))` - Grab everything inside the inner curly braces and group it
3. `(?:.*)` - Group anything up to the next `}`
4. `}` - Continue searching for the next `}` (but don't group it)
5. `(.*)` - Group anything after that

This can be seen in JavaScript here:

```js
var regex = /({.*(?={))(.*(?<=.*}))(?:.*)}(.*)/g;
var string = 'The sentense { he said "hello, {somebody}" } got a something.';

string.replace(regex, function(match, g1, g2, g3) {
  console.log(match);
  console.log(g1);
  console.log(g2);
  console.log(g3);
});
```

And can be seen working on **[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/ewmvFD/1/)**.

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the outer braces is in quotes. Doesn't work if the string contains newlines.

Comment: My first comment refers to your first (and unchanged) regex. Your second regex is just a syntax error.

Comment: This only works in Chrome v62+: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent/50434875#50434875

Comment: .. and fails to handle many possible cases: https://regex101.com/r/ogG3zB/1