# Regex, selecting from second regex expression if only it is not in first regex expression

Tags: html, regex

For example- I have this text

> `www.google.com`
>
> `<a href="www.google.com"> Google Homepage </a>`

I wrote this `(<a.*<\/a>)` which captures anchor tag and this `(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` which selects any text which starts with `www.` but what i want it selects only `www.google.com` not the one inside anchor tag.

anything through which I can completely ignore anchor tag and select text only from remaining text.

To be more precise a regex which can: NOT OF `(<a.*<\/a>)` AND `(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))`

Hope, I'm clear with my question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Do not try to parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6320039)

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or what's your context?

Comment: yeah, I'm using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to select each url (starting with an www.) when it is not in the href attribut

This will work with an negative lookbehind

```
(?<!href=")(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))
```

This regex will select the url when there is no href=" before it.

Be aware js does not support a negative lookbehind, tested on https://regex101.com/

Edit due to addtitons in the comments:
If you want to sort out everything in an html-tag (between before closing `>`) this should work for you:

```
(?![^<]*>)(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)
```

It's an negative lookahead saying that it should not match when having an unlimited times not `<` followed by `>`

Good thing about negative lookahead is, that it is supported in JS :)

Comment: thanks for helping, any suggestions for this `sandeep.gupta@xyz.com` `<a href="mailto:sandeep.gupta@xyz.com"> Sandeep Gupta </a>`

Comment: I'm trying this regex - `(?<!mailto:)(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)`

Comment: the problem here is, that this will match the mail-adress starting from the second char

Comment: can you please explain :/ how this works - `(?![^<]*>)` btw thanks for helping.

Comment: This is a negative lookahead - so searching for what comes after the actual searched expression `[^>]*>` means *not* the character `>` for unlimited times followed by an `>`

Comment: One more doubt, `(?![^<]*>)([^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` this is what i used to select urls starting from `www` but not with `http://www` so this works fine but is including a white space infront of the selected text. what could be the optimal solution to this problem?

Comment: what about `(?![^<]*>)(?<!\/)(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` adding a negativ lookbehind for the `/`. Be aware that negativelookbehind is not supported in JS but was assed to the ES defintion this Year.
So this solution is not save to work in JS at the moment

Comment: Though I can use negative look behind but don't to use here because of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) and `(?![^<]*>)(?<!\/)(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))`

Comment: `(?![^<]*>)([^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` why this inlcudes extra space ?

Comment: what if I want only anchor tag to be considered while doing this? `(?![^<a]*>)(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` i tried this

Comment: your example `(?![^<]*>)([^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$)) ` does include an extra space since `([^\/])` selects one character *not* `/` so this is any character else than the `/`

Comment: `(?![^<a]*>)(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))` the problem here is that `[]` forms a group of characters... not an special order of characters, you basically can not search for `<a` at this point

Comment: to learn regex there are several ressources e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions or https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex or https://regexone.com/

Comment: is there any way to do this, `(?!([^\<]+)<\/a>)(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])` I'm using this but it fails for the case when we have angular brace inside anchor tag. any help ASAP!

Comment: search for this particular tag only, starting from `<a` and ending with `</a>`