# React-Native: JavaScript regular expression exception (Invalid group) on release mode

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I wrote following function in order to parse available image sizes inside `srcset` attribute for each `img` element and return it as array.
Everything works as expected when the debug mode is on, but once I disable the debug mode, the app would crash and throw following error:

[Error: invalid regular expression invalid group specifier name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpxT7.png)

```
export function srcsetParser(htmlString) {

  let result = [];
  let images = htmlString.match(/<img\s+[^>]*srcset="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/g); // Finding img tags inside html string

  images && images.forEach(image => {
    let srcsets = image.match(/(?<=srcset=").+?(?=\")/g); //Select srcset value

    var urls = srcsets[0].split(", ");
    urls.forEach(url => {
      let temp = url.split(" ");
      result.push(temp[0]);
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the regex and why is it so only when debug mode is off ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

The browser support isn’t great, but [JavaScript now allows lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875). The old answer is left below.

---

JavaScript regex doesn’t support lookbehinds. You can do it another way:

```
  images && images.forEach(image => {
    let srcsets = image.match(/srcset="(.+?)(?=\")/); //Select srcset value

    var urls = srcsets[1].split(", ");
    urls.forEach(url => {
      let temp = url.split(" ");
      result.push(temp[0]);
    });
  });
```

Comment: but `/srcset="(.+?)(?=\")/g`  would include `srcset=`, is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: @EhsanAhmadizadeh I also changed `srcsets[0]` to `srcsets[1]`. `srcset=` should not be included.

Comment: But `srcsets[1]` is undefined for me!

Comment: @EhsanAhmadizadeh Sorry, you have to also remove the `g` flag. Updated.

Comment: That did it. Thanks
but why does it return two results instead of one ?
There's no way with regex to just extract the text after `srcset="` till the next occurrence of `"` ?

Comment: @EhsanAhmadizadeh Great. Glad I could help. It returns two results because it uses a capture group, which you can look up if you’re curious. There‘s no way to do it without that using JavaScript regex. Other languages can do it.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875, support for lookbehinds was added to the ECMAScript specification in early 2018. Supported in Node.js v9 and Chrome 62, but not in Firefox and Edge.