# Regex doesn't work with IE 11

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-11

I wrote a regex, which works fine in Chrome, but not in IE 11 and Edge.

```
 /(?<=MERGEFIELD\s\\plain\\f0\\fs24\s)([a-z]*_[0-9]*)(?=})/g
```

IE 11 gives me the error: "Unexpected quantifier".
I tried with blackslash before ? (\?).
The error does not appear, but the Regex does not work either.

Comment: it doesn't work with Edge either

Comment: Chrome is going above and beyond in this case.  This would have failed in Firefox too, due to your lookbehind.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3569104

Comment: I got it. I changed my regex in /MERGEFIELD\s\\plain\\f0\\fs24\s([a-z]*_[0-9]*)}/g.
I've put the part I'd like to get in paranthesis. ([a-z]*_[0-9]*).
After this I use  .match to get the array of strings:
str.match(basicRtfPattern)
This returns not only the part in the paranthesis, but the whole MERGEFIELD tag.
Is there a way to obtain only the part in brackets?

Comment: I managed this: I get all occurencies with the g constructor.
After this I loop the resulting  array with the same regexp but without g at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native: JavaScript regular expression exception (Invalid group) on release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367051/react-native-javascript-regular-expression-exception-invalid-group-on-release)