# How to match the start/end of a multiline string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

It should be very simple, but I cannot figure out, how to match the beginning and the end of a multiline string. Say, I want to know, whether the string contains `foo` at the beginning of the first line.

```js
str = "foo\nbar";
reg = /^foo/m;
console.log( reg.test( str ) ); // → true
```

But if I swap `foo` and `bar`, thus placing `foo` in the second line, the result will (though shouldn't) be the same:

```js
str = "bar\nfoo";
reg = /^foo/m;
console.log( reg.test( str ) ); // → true
```

So, is there a way to catch the beginning and the end of a multiline string?

Comment: Try [`^foo[\s\S]+bar$`](https://regex101.com/r/uJgTSF/1)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the multiline mode flag "m".
With that flag, you are not just matching at the start of the text, but at the start of the lines. So when you have the line break \n before foo, this is the start of a new line, which will match the start query ^foo.

Here is a link with some more info:
https://javascript.info/regexp-multiline-mode

**Solution:** as was said in the comment section below by Jacob, just take out the multiline mode if you only wish to match the start of the string,

```js
str = "bar\nfoo";
reg = /^foo/;
console.log( reg.test( str ) ); // → false
```

Comment: It sounds to me like the `m` flag isn't needed at all. Just remove that, and `^` and `$` work correctly.

Comment: @AmsaIK I understand why it matches. But what will be the solution to my question?

Comment: So, taking away the multiline flag is the only solution. Very inconvenient... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: It's not the only solution. You could use a negative [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875/3390419) `reg = /(?<!\n)^foo/m;`, depending on your environment.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness If I'm not mistaken (can't check now), lookbehind isn't supported yet outside of chrome.

Comment: That's correct, hence why I specified *depending on your environment*.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you may not need to use complicated regex at all. If you are always certain that you want to check if the *very* beginning of the string is "foo", then check if `str.slice(0,3) === "foo"`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but I'm looking for a more general solution.