# Change Image source in Markdown text using Node JS

Tags: node.js, markdown

I have some markdown text containing image references but those are relative paths & I need to modify those to absolute paths using NodeJS script. Is there any way to achieve the same in simple way ?

Example:

Source

```
![](myImage.png?raw=true)
```

Result

```
![](www.example.com/myImage.png?raw=true)
```

I have multiple images in the markdwon content that I need to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this working example: https://repl.it/repls/BlackJuicyCommands

First of all you need the read the file with `fs.readFile()` and parse the `Buffer` to a `string`.

Now you got access to the text of the file, you need the replace every image path with a new image path. One way to capture it is with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You could for example look for  `](ANY_IMAGE_PATH.ANY_IMAGE_EXTENSION`. We're only interested in replacing the `ANY_IMAGE_PATH` part.

An example regex could be (this could be improved!) (see it live in action here: https://regex101.com/r/xRioBq/1):

```
const regex = /\]\((.+)(?=(\.(svg|gif|png|jpe?g)))/g
```

This will look for a literal `]` followed by a literal `(` followed by any sequence (that's the `.+`) until it finds a literal `.` followed by either `svg`, `gif`,`png`, or `jpeg` / `jpg`. the `g` after the regex is necessary to match all occurences, not only the first.

Javascript/node (< version 9) [does not support lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent). I've used a regex that includes the `](` before the image path and then will filter it out later (or you could use a more complex regex).

The `(.+)` captures the image path as a group. Then you can use the replace function of the string. The replace function accepts the regex as first argument. The second argument can be a function which receives as first argument the full match (in this case `](image_path_without_extension` and as the following arguments any captured group.

[image]

Change the url with the node modules `path`  or `url` and return the captured group (underneath I've called that argument `imagePath`). Because we're also replacing the `](`, that should be included in the return value.

```js
const url = require('url');
const replacedText = data.toString().replace(regex, (fullResult, imagePath) => {
    const newImagePath = url.resolve('http://www.example.org', imagePath)
    return `](${newImagePath}`;
})
```

[See the repl example to see it live in action.](https://repl.it/repls/BlackJuicyCommands) Note: in the repl example it is written to a different file. Use the same file name if you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue yesterday, and came up with this solution.

```
const markdownReplaced = markdown.replace(
  /(?<=\]\()(.+)(?=(\)))/g,
  (url) => `www.example.com/${url}`,
);
```

The regex finds anything starts with `](` and ends with `)`, without including the capturing group, which is the original URL itself.