# How would I go about splitting a string by two brackets with regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord.js

I have been working with Discord.js and Node to a quick bot to look up something. I need a way to find all the occurrences that appear between two square brackers and store them in an array of strings. For now I'm using string-split() with some regex, but I am unsure of the regex to use.

I have tried using a few different ones, including `/[^\[\[]+(?=\]\])/g` and `\[\[(.*?)\]\]` - I dont mind having the actual brackets in the results, I can remove them manually with string.replace().

I am also working on a fallback with the normal string.split() and other string functions, not relying on regex, but I'm still curious about a possible regex version.

The result with the first regex is totally incorrect. For example, if I try `"does [[this]] work [at all]?"` the output is "[[]]" and "[at all]", when it really shouldn't take the "at all", but it shouls show the "[[this]]".

With the second regex I get somewhat closer, it gives back "this"(correct) and "[at all]" (again, it shouldn't take the "at all").

I don't mind having the brackets in the output, I can remove them manually myself, but I need to find all occurrences that are specifically between two brackets.

Comment: `[^\[\[]` define a char-set (all char that is not `\\`)

Comment: and your second regex just works well https://regex101.com/r/z6qpHJ/1

Comment: it should be `"does [[this]] work [at all]?".match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g)`, and this at least work in my browser (you don't even need the g flag)

Comment: with .match it only matches the first result, with or without the global flag 

Comment: `"it's [[not]] the case for my browser [[at all]].".match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g)`

Comment: I should have made it clear, I am using node for this. that does work on my browser too, just not with the node bot

Comment: node 10.15.0, windows 10, works well.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875/5424988), you might use a positive lookabehind which  in Node.js v6 is behind a flag and v9 without a flag  `(?<=\[\[)[^\][]+(?=\]\])` See a  [demo](https://repl.it/repls/ParallelSleepyButton)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\[\[([^[\]]|(?R))*\]\]
```

What you are trying to do is called [Matching Balanced Constructs](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive). More info at the link.

Upon further testing, unfortunately JS does not support `(?R)` so this becomes far more difficult. You could use the [XRegExp.matchRecursive](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive) addon from the [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp) package.

And your expression `\[\[(.*?)\]\]` should work. Working example below.

```js
var str = 'does [[this]] work [at all] with another double [[here]]?';

var result = str.match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g);

var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
newDiv.innerHTML = result;
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: with the ?R it just errors on execution, with "Invalid regular expression: Invalid group".

removing ?R (so that it works on regex101.com) and testing with `does [[this]] work [please] [[cmon]] bot` it returns "does", "s", "[please]", "n", and "bot".

Comment: Ah, I just noticed JS doesn't support `(?R)`. I'll update the answer in a few minutes with a JS compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution

```
var str = "does [[this]] work [at all]?";
var regexp = /\[([a-z0-9\s]+)\]/ig;

var resultArray = str.match(regexp); 
resultArray = resultArray.map((item) => {
  return item.replace(/(\[|\])/g, "");
})

console.log(resultArray);
```