# Alternative way of writing this regex as it fails to run in other browser than chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
  const str = '1.22.333'; 
  const patt = /^(?:\d+\.?)+(?<!\.)$/;
  const result = str.match(patt);
```

It only works in Chrome. In Firefox I get:

> SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

https://jsbin.com/colehogema/edit?html,js,output

Is there any other way of writing this regex so other browsers can run it?

Requirements:

- Start with number
- End with number
- Numbers separated with one dot
- Only a single number with no dots is valid

Comment: What are the requirements for the regex? What do you want to match?

Comment: negative lookbehinds are not supported in Firefox right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal repetition without any lookarounds:

```
  const str = '1.22.333'; 
  const patt = /^(?:\d+\.)*\d+$/;
  const result = str.match(patt);
  console.log(result);
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cuEvZ7/2/)

Explanation:

- you match digits ending with a dot with `\d+\.`, .e.g `123.`
- you repeat this zero or more times: `123.32.12.`
- at the end you match just digits: `\d+`

I've discussed thoroughly matching digits with separators in a [blogpost about regex performance](https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698). It's worth noting that your initial regex was prone to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) in `(?:\d+\.?)+` part.

As a VLAZ noted, negative lookbehinds (`(?<!\.)`) are only supported by chrome.
More about lookarounds in JS: [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: A single number without dot is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:(?:\d+\.){2})?\d+$/
```

This matches either three numbers separated by two dots or a number. If the count of numbers separated by dots can be anything then the regex will be :

```
/^(?:\d+\.)*\d+$/
```

as answered by @mrzasa [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995386/1338382).

Regex explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/oyC2bu/2/)

```js
const str = '1.22.333'; 
const patt = /^(?:(?:\d+\.){2})?\d+$/;
const result = str.match(patt);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works only with 3 or 1 group of digits.