# How to capture and replace int and float in a string without affecting the date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like below

Your statistics:
The trend is going up.
The most recent value for x*y on  2018-12-09 is 469.44.
The max was 2896 on 2018-12-08 and  min was 23.1 on 2018-12-08.
Additionally, the median is 367.95 and the mode is 23.1.
There is higher margin for error/mistake.

As you can see I got some `float` and `int` in the string. I need to replace all those occurences with `span` tag surrounding those occurrences

Here I managed to do something basic like replacing the instances of `float` and `int` with `XXX`. But the problem is there are occurrences of `date` too and that screws up the operation. So this is what I do:

```
var string = "Your statistics:<br>The trend is going up.<br>The most recent value for x*y on  2018-12-09 is 469.44.<br>The max was 2896 on 2018-12-08 and  min was 23.1 on 2018-12-08.<br>Additionally, the median is 367.95 and the mode is 23.1.<br>There is higher margin for error/mistake."

string = string.replace(/\d+/g, "XXX");
console.log(string)
```

This is what I get:

```
Your statistics:<br>The trend is going up.<br>The most recent value for x*y on  XXX-XXX-XXX is XXX.XXX.<br>The max was XXX on XXX-XXX-XXX and  min was XXX.XXX on XXX-XXX-XXX.<br>Additionally, the median is XXX.XXX and the mode is XXX.XXX.<br>There is higher margin for error/mistake.
```

Now what I want is replace all occurrences of `float` and `int` with a `span` tag surrounding them something like `469.44` be replaced with `<span>469.44</span>`, `2896` be replaced with `<span>2896<span>`

So final string would become something like:

```
Your statistics:<br>The trend is going up.<br>The most recent value for x*y on  2018-12-09 is <span>469.44</span>.<br>The max was <span>2896</span> on 2018-12-08 and  min was <span>23.1</span> on 2018-12-08.<br>Additionally, the median is <span>367.95</span> and the mode is <span>23.1</span>.<br>There is higher margin for error/mistake.
```

How do I accomplish this ensuring `dates` are not messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job without lookbehind:

```js
var string = "Your statistics:<br>The trend is going up.<br>The most recent value for x*y on  2018-12-09 is -469.44.<br>The max was 2896 on 2018-12-08 and  min was -23.1 on 2018-12-08.<br>Additionally, the median is 367.95 and the mode is 23.1.<br>There is higher margin for error/mistake."

string = string.replace(/(\s)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([.\s])/g, "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
console.log(string)
```

Comment: I'm so glad we have SO so we don't have to actually the horrors of regex

Comment: @SouvikRay: De rien ;), glad it helps.

Comment: @Toto Hi friend! I needed a small help. Is there any way negative numbers can be covered too? Like `-124.33`, `-21`, `-0.22` etc. So I want both the minus and the number to be covered. You may post an edit to your answer with your modified regex.

Comment: @SouvikRay: Just add `-?` before the first `\d+`, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without lookbehind.

```js
var string = "Your statistics:<br>The trend is going up.<br>The most recent value for x*y on  2018-12-09 is 469.44.<br>The max was 2896 on 2018-12-08 and  min was 23.1 on 2018-12-08.<br>Additionally, the median is 367.95 and the mode is 23.1.<br>There is higher margin for error/mistake."

let newStr = string.replace(/(\d+[^-]\d+|\s\d\s)(?=[^-0-9])/g,str=>`<span>${str}</span>`)
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: This will not work for numbers that contain only 1 digit.

Comment: A serial downvoter was in action, all answers get downvoted! But there is another problem with your regex, it change `blah 12 34 blah` into `blah <span>12 34</span> blah` instead of `blah <span>12</span> <span>34</span> blah`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Anyway I didn't down vote anything. I am here to learn from others and help others. Not to compete with anyone. I don't know how I can prove that, but I know I didn't down vote anything :) . Thanks a lot again for the feedback!

Comment: Forgetting what you just said and back to discussion. This problem doesn't has two consecutive numbers. So I think this should be still valid.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm sure it wasn't you that downvoted. Sometimes people downvote without explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<!-\d*)\d+(\.\d+)?(?!\d*-)/g`

• `(?<!something)` — negative lookbehind. We don't need to capture the numbers, which have `-\d*` behind.

   • `\d` — digit, matches any digit from 0 to 9. 

   • `*` — zero or multiple times

• `\d+(\.\d+)?` — `\d+` any digit from 1 to multiple times (int numers),

   • `(\.\d+)` — `\.` dot symbol, `\d+` any digits (float numbers), 

   • `?` — "lazy" match, means "zero or one match"

• `(?!\d*-)` — negative lookahead. We don't need digit with `-` as well.

```js
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

bubu.innerHTML = bubu.innerHTML
  .replace(/(?<!-\d*)\d+(\.\d+)?(?!\d*-)/g, match => '<span class="red">' + match + '</span>')
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="bubu">Your statistics:
The trend is going up.
The most recent value for x*y on 2018-12-09 is 469.44.
The max was 2896 on 2018-12-08 and min was 23.1 on 2018-12-08.
Additionally, the median is 367.95 and the mode is 23.1.
There is higher margin for error/mistake.</p>
```

Comment: hey do you want to recheck your solution? The code snippet doesn't run and when I try to run it locally in my system, I get this error `'Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind - it works, but has pure browser support. Now trying to find old version of lookbehind) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent maybe...