# RegEx - contain specific number after period

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have strings similar to; *First Half Goals 1.5/2*. The text at the beginning can be anything so cannot depend on that as part of the RegEx as it varies. What I want to do is to match the number sequence at the end. Test samples would be:

- 5
- 0.5/1
- 2.5/3
- 147

The sequence can either contain a slash or it cannot. If it contains a slash, there **must** be a value after it - either integer or decimal. The value before the decimal *(if one is present)* can be any number of digits - **\d+** - but the value after should **must** be *0* or *5* - **(0|5)**. The 1st value before the slash *(/)* is either an integer or a decimal. If the sequence contains a slash, then the number after is also either a integer or a decimal. All values are positive.

The main point of this RegEx is that I need it to only match **once**. The was the RegEx I was using:

`(\d(\.(0|5))?\/\d(\.(0|5)))|(\d\.(0|5))|(\d)`

The issue with the regex above is that the example string I use; *First Half Goals 1.5/2* matched **twice**. Once on the *1.5* & the 2nd on the *2*. I have now altered it to be this:

`\d+(\.(0|5))?(\/?\d+(\.(0|5))?)?`

This is slightly better **but** if I give the test sample; *1.6/2*, it will match *6/2*. This will be because the decimal section on the former number is optional. I'm not sure if a lookbehind would come in handy here, I don't have much experience with them. Sadly the text beforehand is so unpredictable otherwise I could trim the string to only get the wanted substring & then match from the start of the string but can't do that. An outline of what should match & what should not:

```
1         // Match
5.5       // Match
7.8       // No Match
0/0.5     // Match
147/147.5 // Match
2.        // No Match
6.5/      // No Match
7.0/8     // Match
10.0      // Match
1./2.5    // No Match
5./6      // No Match
/157      // No Match
/4.5      // No Match
```

I've tried to explain as best I could but if you need more details then I'll provide them

Comment: Use `/\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.[05])?(?:\/\d+(?:\.[05])?)?$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpXkq5/3)

Comment: Negative Lookbehind does not work on all browsers: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

Comment: @Spirit I should have mentioned that this is backend & Node so lookbehinds will work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that RegEx seems to work well. I have just edited it to be this: `\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.[05])?(?:\/\d+(?:\.[05])?)?$` so that the 2nd value (if decimal) will only match 0 or 5. The case it doesn't work on is if I have `1./2` or `1./2.5` or something similar. I would expect it to not match but it does match on the value after the slash. Can this be amended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js, RegExp supports lookbehinds and you may use

```
/\b(?<!\d\.|\/)\d+(?:\.[05])?(?:\/\d+(?:\.[05])?)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpXkq5/5)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\d\.|\/)` - no digit + dot or a slash are allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.[05])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[05]` - `0` or `5`
- `(?:\/\d+(?:\.[05])?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\/\d+` -  a `/` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[05])?` - an optional sequence of a dot and then `0` or `5`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Great answer! I think 1 I left out that shouldn't match though is `/147.5`. If I put that on where the slash proceeds a value, it will match the value. I would expect that it wouldn't as it looks in the RegEx that there must be 1+ digits proceeding it but it does match. If you amend it to not match that, I'll accept your answer