# Invalid regular expression in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-chrome, safari

I use this code to validate the form of the username:

```
var nameRegex = /^(?=.{3,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/;
var validUsername = usernameText.value.match(nameRegex);

if (validUsername == null) {
    //Username is not valid  
} else {
    //Username is valid
}
```

It works fine is Chrome, but when I test it in Safari, both iOS and MacOS I get this error message in the console: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`.

I'm pretty new to regular expressions and don't know how to modify the code to make it work in all browsers, or another solution to validate the username.

Comment: does the error go away if you remove `(?<![_.])` ? as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility lookbehind isn't supported on safari

Comment: also, you could use `test` method to get `true/false` instead of using `match` method and then checking for `null`, etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent has some alternate suggestions for lookbehind.. but I think you could use `(?!.*[_.]$)` at the start of the expression instead of `(?<![_.])`

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind