# How to match all strings with a specific REGEX pattern that do not start with a defined character without using a negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I currently have a usecase on which I want to match all `http://` and `https://` strings in a text but only when they do not start with a `"` or `'` using JavaScript.
If they start with another character, e.g., a whitespace, I still only want to match the `http://` or `https://` without the preceding character.

My current regex uses a negative lookbehind but I just realized that this is not supported in Safari:

```
/(?<!["'])(https?:\/\/)/gm
```

So what would be an alternative for using a negative lookbehind to match the following strings in a text:

- `http://` -> should match `http://`
- `https://` -> should match `https://`
- `xhttps://` -> should match `https://` whereby `x` can be any character except `"` and `'`
- `"https://` -> should NOT match at all

Comment: [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407)

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*["']https?:\/\/).*(https?:\/\/)/gm`

Comment: @anubhava This would match only the first `https?://` in a text. My goal would be to match all `https?://` even when they are in the middle of a text.

Comment: ok then use: `(?:^|[^"'])(https?:\/\/)`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, looks good! It just also matches the preceding character. So for `xhttps://` I only want to match `https://` but it matches the full `xhttps://`.

Comment: Don't look at full match, look at captured group #1

Comment: @anubhava Yes, you are right, that's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of lookbebind here, use character class and groups:

```js
const vars = ['http://', 'https://', 'xhttps://', '"https://']
const re = /(?:[^'"]|^)(https?:\/\/)/
vars.forEach(x => 
   console.log(x, '- >', (x.match(re) || ['',''])[1])
)
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/o6hF7F/2):

```js
(?:[^'"]|^)(https?:\/\/)
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this regex: `/^[a-z]+:\/\//gm`

**Example**:

```
const pattern = /^[a-z]+:\/\//gm
const string = `http://
https://
xhttp://
"http://
'https://`
console.log(string.match(pattern));
// Output: [ 'http://', 'https://', 'xhttp://' ]
```