# How to grab URLs in JavaScript without harming embedded objects and inline URL

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a RegExp to grab and encode URLs in JavaScript.
This works fine but, it introduced a bug into my app.
I have a span Element which is used to display Emojis like this:

`<span style="background:url(http://localhost/res/emo/face/E004.png)"></span>`

Now, I'm using this Regular Expression to grab and convert anything URL into actual HTML clickable links:

`/((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/ig`

This ended up encoding the emoji URL into a clickable link.
Can anyone adjust that Code to Ignore URLs inside Elements or embedded Objects???

Please I need help!

This is the code:

```
var urlRegex = /((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/ig;
return txt.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
  var hyperlink = url;
  if(!hyperlink.match('^https?:\/\/')) {
    hyperlink = 'http://' + hyperlink;
  }

  return `<a href="/?away=${encodeURIComponent(hyperlink)}&ref_component=hyperApp" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${url}</a>`;
});
```

I don't that the URLS inside

`<span style="background:url(http://localhost/res/emo/face/E004.png)"></span>`

were touched.

Comment: We'd probably have to see that code to make any recommendations. However, without seeing it I would recommend adding a class to all elements that you don't want to be considered. With that in place you can set up some filtering to encode only the elements you want to consider.

Comment: can you show the code that runs the regex? is it cycling through each element? How are you impolementing that?

Comment: So, I have added the code that encodes the URLs

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use negative look behind, which has limited support in JavaScript.  (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434875/6853740)

Simply adding negative look behind to your existing regex still doesn't work as expected:

`((?<!url\()(https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)` still matches "E004.png" in your example.  Even other URL regexs from this post ([What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)) also match that.  You may need to consider only looking for links that start with http:// or https:// which may help you recraft a regex that will only match full URLs.